# How to get names of enum entries?

Tags: enums, typescript

I would like to iterate a TypeScript enum object and get each enumerated symbol name, for example:
enum myEnum { entry1, entry2 }

```
for (var entry in myEnum) { 
    // use entry's name here, e.g., "entry1"
}
```

Comment: this tiny [enum-for](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enum-for) package has `getAllEnumValues` and `getAllEnumKeys` for your purpose

Comment: I have created [a PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/42465) ([issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42457)) to add native support for `for (const [name, value] of MyEnum) {` to Typescript. Hopefully this will be easier one day!

Comment: Must have been to difficult to provide a `EnumType.name()` method.

Comment: I  found this article useful https://www.technicalfeeder.com/2021/07/mastering-enum-in-typescript/

Answer (score 380, accepted):

The code you posted will work; it will print out all the members of the enum, including the values of the enum members. For example, the following code:

```
enum myEnum { bar, foo }

for (var enumMember in myEnum) {
   console.log("enum member: ", enumMember);
}
```

Will print the following:

```
Enum member: 0
Enum member: 1
Enum member: bar
Enum member: foo
```

If you instead want only the member names, and not the values, you could do something like this:

```
for (var enumMember in myEnum) {
   var isValueProperty = Number(enumMember) >= 0
   if (isValueProperty) {
      console.log("enum member: ", myEnum[enumMember]);
   }
}
```

That will print out just the names:

```
Enum member: bar  
Enum member: foo
```

Caveat: this slightly relies on an implementation detail: TypeScript compiles enums to a JS object with the enum values being members of the object. If TS decided to implement them different in the future, the above technique could break.

Comment: To be clear, the above answer still works as of TS 2.3. However, if you use "const enum", rather than just "enum", only then will it not work. Using const enum is basically telling TS to do a search-and-replace; every place you use MyEnum.Foo, it will be replaced with a corresponding numeric value.

Comment: I think the `+enumMember >= 0` should be `isFinite(+enumMember)` because negative or floating point values get reverse mapped too. ([Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.1.6&ssl=5&ssc=65&pln=5&pc=51#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3gKCpqALYAbPAeygF4oBaARgCYBmAOmoBoMsB3QgJzwBNSoARB248BaAL5oAxoRABnQnmD0iAcwAUAeQBGAK2BSALvQDWwOHPXwkkAJS2oAekdQA2gNwFCApoKp1GH0FhXgEAXSA))

Comment: Enum entries can be string with [leading zeros](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9gGzgJygbwFBSs4ATKAXigEYAaLKAIgAYSqioAmDAXyA) like `00111`, you need to exclude these too

Comment: As of TS 4, doesn't work with numeric and heterogenous enums.

Answer (score 845):

Though the answer is already provided, Almost no one pointed to the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings)

Here's a snippet

```
enum SampleEnum {
    A,
     
}
let nameOfA = SampleEnum[SampleEnum.A]; // "A"
```

Keep in mind that string enum members do not get a reverse mapping generated at all.

Comment: How about displaying `0` or `1` from this enum ? `export enum Octave { ZERO = 0, ONE = 1 }`

Comment: @jbojcic  Is it about situation: `enum Enum {"A"}; let nameOfA = Enum[Enum.A];`? As of typescript@2.9.2 it works fine for me...

Comment: How about looping through values?

Comment: In JS enum is an object of `[value]: name` so you can get all values like that `Object.keys(enum)`, all names `Object.values(enum)` and iterate in one go using `for(const [value, name] of Object.entries(enum)) { ... }`. Beware that when you get values they will be strings, not numbers as you would expect (since in JS keys of object are strings).

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question that was asked. Yes, the facts stated here are correct, and one could deduce an answer from it, but there is no direct answer.

Comment: Odd how you can't use this to call a static property of a class... Having `class S { static SP = 1 }` and `enum E { SP }`, you can call `E[E.SP] // "SP"` and `S["SP"]`, but not `S[E[E.SP]]`.

Comment: Would be more clear if you name the enum something other than Enum

Comment: `let filteredKeys = Object.entries(AnimalEnum).filter(([,value]) => value === AnimalEnum.DOG || value === AnimalEnum.CAT).map(([key,]) => {     return key })`

Answer (score 134):

For me an easier, practical and direct way to understand what is going on, is that the following enumeration:

```
enum colors { red, green, blue };
```

Will be converted essentially to this:

```
var colors = { red: 0, green: 1, blue: 2,
               [0]: "red", [1]: "green", [2]: "blue" }
```

Because of this, the following will be true:

```
colors.red === 0
colors[colors.red] === "red"
colors["red"] === 0
```

This creates a easy way to get the name of an enumerated as follows:

```
var color: colors = colors.red;
console.log("The color selected is " + colors[color]);
```

It also creates a nice way to convert a string to an enumerated value.

```
var colorName: string = "green";
var color: colors = colors.red;
if (colorName in colors) color = colors[colorName];
```

The two situations above are far more common situation, because usually you are far more interested in the name of a specific value and serializing values in a generic way.

Comment: This is a nice description of how TS enums work, but doesn't answer the question of how to "iterate" over "each enumerated symbol name".

Comment: Best example so far of how enums work! Thank you.

Answer (score 105):

If you only search for the names and iterate later use:

```
Object.keys(myEnum).map(key => myEnum[key]).filter(value => typeof value === 'string') as string[];
```

Comment: Or with the ES2017 lib: `Object.values(myEnum).filter(value => typeof value === 'string') as string[];`

Comment: I needed to create a dict, and I used your answer as a startpoint. If someone else needs it, `Object.values(myEnum).filter(value => typeof value === 'string').map(key => { return {id: myEnum[key], type: key }; });`

Comment: or just Object.values(myEnum).filter(isNaN) as string[];

Comment: Isn't `Object.keys(myEnum)` enough to get an array with of key names in an enum object?

Comment: best way so far is `Object.entries(temp1).splice(Object.keys(temp1).length/2)` so we get the entries

Comment: For `enum Test1 { A = "C", B = "D"}` returns `["C", "D"]`. That's values, not keys.

Comment: @BrunoNegrãoZica ```Object.keys(myEnum)``` returns not only string keys of enum but also theis corresponding index in enum.
Like
```ts
enum Color { Black, White }
console.log(Object.keys(Color)) // '0', '1', 'Black', 'White'
```

Answer (score 64):

Assuming you stick to the rules and only produce enums with numeric values, you can use this code. This correctly handles the case where you have a name that is coincidentally a valid number

```
enum Color {
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue,
    "10" // wat
}

var names: string[] = [];
for(var n in Color) {
    if(typeof Color[n] === 'number') names.push(n);
}
console.log(names); // ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', '10']
```

Comment: **Warning** In modern typescript (tsc 2.5.2 atm) you are not even allowed to have a numeric string as a key to begin with. As such Himango's answer is better, since it covers all cases and has no downsides.

Comment: `Object.prototype.foo = 1;`

Answer (score 51):

It seems that none of the answers here will work with string-enums in `strict`-mode.

Consider enum as:

```
enum AnimalEnum {
  dog = "dog", cat = "cat", mouse = "mouse"
}
```

Accessing this with `AnimalEnum["dog"]` may result in an error like:

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'typeof AnimalEnum'.ts(7053)`.

Proper solution for that case, write it as:

```
AnimalEnum["dog" as keyof typeof AnimalEnum]
```

Comment: Brilliant solution for using the `keyof` with `typeof`! Other solution seems pretty opaque, but after all I think Typescript needs to keep improve on DX - Developer Experience for Enum

Comment: Not so brilliant when the value is not the same as the key

Comment: This solution is good when you want to map enum values when passed a key,

Comment: This solution was so minimal, yet worked perfectly for my purposes. Excellent work! 
I used this in a map function for an api response. Much simpler than iterating though the object values or keys and working back from there. Very much appreciated!

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 33):

As of TypeScript 2.4, enums can contain string intializers https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html

This allows you to write:

```
 enum Order {
      ONE = "First",
      TWO = "Second"
 }

console.log(`One is ${Order.ONE.toString()}`);
```

and get this output:

> One is First

Comment: How does it "iterate" over "each enumerated symbol name"? This is not an answer to the given question at all.

Answer (score 32):

With current TypeScript Version 1.8.9 I use typed Enums:

```
export enum Option {
    OPTION1 = <any>'this is option 1',
    OPTION2 = <any>'this is option 2'
}
```

with results in this Javascript object:

```
Option = {
    "OPTION1": "this is option 1",
    "OPTION2": "this is option 2",
    "this is option 1": "OPTION1",
    "this is option 2": "OPTION2"
}
```

so I have to query through keys and values and only return values:

```
let optionNames: Array<any> = [];    
for (let enumValue in Option) {
    let optionNameLength = optionNames.length;

    if (optionNameLength === 0) {
        this.optionNames.push([enumValue, Option[enumValue]]);
    } else {
        if (this.optionNames[optionNameLength - 1][1] !== enumValue) {
            this.optionNames.push([enumValue, Option[enumValue]]);
        }
    }
}
```

And I receive the option keys in an Array:

```
optionNames = [ "OPTION1", "OPTION2" ];
```

Comment: well, code says different thing, you will get: `optionNames = [["OPTION1", "this is option 1"], ["OPTION2", "this is option 2"]]`, but overall I appreciate your idea of removing double reversed entries, everyone else here considers that value is always a number

Comment: @DimaKaraush Not everyone. Also this answer relies on order of keys in objects, and is blatantly wrong.

Comment: After fixing issues with the code, it produces `[["OPTION1", "this is option 1"], ["OPTION2", "this is option 2"]]` instead. Even if you take first element of each of those tuples, it fails on `enum Test2 { A, B }` by producing `["0", "1", "A", "B"]`.

Answer (score 30):

This solution work too.

```
enum ScreenType {
    Edit = 1,
    New = 2,
    View = 4
}

var type: ScreenType = ScreenType.Edit;

console.log(ScreenType[type]); //Edit
```

Comment: Why it prints 'undefined' for me? Any idea?

Comment: How does it "iterate" over "each enumerated symbol name"? This is not an answer to the given question at all.

Comment: While you show how to access enums with its array accessor, I recommend adding the iteration part to answer the question

Answer (score 28):

**In a nutshell**

if your `enums` is as below:

```
export enum Colors1 {
  Red = 1,
  Green = 2,
  Blue = 3
}
```

to get specific  text and value:

```
console.log(Colors1.Red); // 1 
console.log(Colors1[Colors1.Red]); // Red
```

to get list of value and text:

```
public getTextAndValues(e: { [s: number]: string }) {
  for (const enumMember in e) {
    if (parseInt(enumMember, 10) >= 0) {
      console.log(e[enumMember]) // Value, such as 1,2,3
      console.log(parseInt(enumMember, 10)) // Text, such as Red,Green,Blue
    }
  }
}
this.getTextAndValues(Colors1)
```

if your `enums` is as below:

```
export enum Colors2 {
  Red = "Red",
  Green = "Green",
  Blue = "Blue"
}
```

to get specific text and value:

```
console.log(Colors2.Red); // Red
console.log(Colors2["Red"]); // Red
```

to get list of value and text:

```
public getTextAndValues(e: { [s: string]: string }) {
  for (const enumMember in e) {
    console.log(e[enumMember]);// Value, such as Red,Green,Blue
    console.log(enumMember); //  Text, such as Red,Green,Blue
  }
}
this.getTextAndValues(Colors2)
```

Comment: Doesn't work with string and heterogenous enums. By the look of `thsi` it's easy to imply the code wasn't ever compiled.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph- I updated my answer, in my opinion, you should not downvote a question because of the Writing error

Comment: I downvoted it, because it's wrong. Numeric enums are not the only type of enums. Also I don't see why numbers have to be non-negative. `enum A { B = -1 }` is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 18):

Another interesting solution [found here](https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/map-your-typescript-enums-e402d406b229) is using ES6 Map:

```
export enum Type {
  low,
  mid,
  high
}

export const TypeLabel = new Map<number, string>([
  [Type.low, 'Low Season'],
  [Type.mid, 'Mid Season'],
  [Type.high, 'High Season']
]);
```

USE

```
console.log(TypeLabel.get(Type.low)); // Low Season


TypeLabel.forEach((label, value) => {
  console.log(label, value);
});

// Low Season 0
// Mid Season 1
// High Season 2
```

Comment: The question asked how to "iterate" over enum's keys. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I added an example showing how to iterate the map

Comment: Unfortunately, it's wrong. `enum Test { A = 0 }`

Answer (score 16):

Let `ts-enum-util` ([github](https://github.com/UselessPickles/ts-enum-util), [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-enum-util)) do the work for you and provide a lot of additional type-safe utilities. Works with both string and numeric enums, properly ignoring the numeric index reverse lookup entries for numeric enums:

String enum:

```
import {$enum} from "ts-enum-util";

enum Option {
    OPTION1 = 'this is option 1',
    OPTION2 = 'this is option 2'
}

// type: ("OPTION1" | "OPTION2")[]
// value: ["OPTION1", "OPTION2"]
const keys= $enum(Option).getKeys();

// type: Option[]
// value: ["this is option 1", "this is option 2"]
const values = $enum(Option).getValues();
```

Numeric enum:

```
enum Option {
    OPTION1,
    OPTION2
}

// type: ("OPTION1" | "OPTION2")[]
// value: ["OPTION1", "OPTION2"]
const keys= $enum(Option).getKeys();

// type: Option[]
// value: [0, 1]
const values = $enum(Option).getValues();
```

Comment: Looks bugged. Code doesn't distinguish between `"0"` and `0`. Also, size of the library is ridiculous.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph - Could you give more detail or an example of where the code fails to distinguish between `"0"` and `0`?

And about the size of the library, are you just looking at the total size of the NPM package? The size of the raw code itself is pretty small. Most of the package size is documentation (code comments and markdown files), and the fully documented source code is included with source maps for debugging.

Comment: For `enum Test { NaN = 'LOL' }` it produces `[]`.

Comment: Also it takes over 1700 lines of code for something that should take 5.

Answer (score 16):

I got tired looking through incorrect answers, and did it myself.

- THIS ONE HAS TESTS.
- Works with all types of enumerations.
- Correctly typed.

```
type EnumKeys<Enum> = Exclude<keyof Enum, number>

const enumObject = <Enum extends Record<string, number | string>>(e: Enum) => {
    const copy = {...e} as { [K in EnumKeys<Enum>]: Enum[K] };
    Object.values(e).forEach(value => typeof value === 'number' && delete copy[value]);
    return copy;
};

const enumKeys = <Enum extends Record<string, number | string>>(e: Enum) => {
    return Object.keys(enumObject(e)) as EnumKeys<Enum>[];
};

const enumValues = <Enum extends Record<string, number | string>>(e: Enum) => {
    return [...new Set(Object.values(enumObject(e)))] as Enum[EnumKeys<Enum>][];
};

enum Test1 { A = "C", B = "D"}
enum Test2 { A, B }
enum Test3 { A = 0, B = "C" }
enum Test4 { A = "0", B = "C" }
enum Test5 { undefined = "A" }
enum Test6 { A = "undefined" }
enum Test7 { A, B = "A" }
enum Test8 { A = "A", B = "A" }
enum Test9 { A = "B", B = "A" }

console.log(enumObject(Test1)); // {A: "C", B: "D"}
console.log(enumObject(Test2)); // {A: 0, B: 1}
console.log(enumObject(Test3)); // {A: 0, B: "C"}
console.log(enumObject(Test4)); // {A: "0", B: "C"}
console.log(enumObject(Test5)); // {undefined: "A"}
console.log(enumObject(Test6)); // {A: "undefined"}
console.log(enumObject(Test7)); // {A: 0,B: "A"}
console.log(enumObject(Test8)); // {A: "A", B: "A"}
console.log(enumObject(Test9)); // {A: "B", B: "A"}

console.log(enumKeys(Test1)); // ["A", "B"]
console.log(enumKeys(Test2)); // ["A", "B"]
console.log(enumKeys(Test3)); // ["A", "B"]
console.log(enumKeys(Test4)); // ["A", "B"]
console.log(enumKeys(Test5)); // ["undefined"]
console.log(enumKeys(Test6)); // ["A"]
console.log(enumKeys(Test7)); // ["A", "B"]
console.log(enumKeys(Test8)); // ["A", "B"]
console.log(enumKeys(Test9)); // ["A", "B"]

console.log(enumValues(Test1)); // ["C", "D"]
console.log(enumValues(Test2)); // [0, 1]
console.log(enumValues(Test3)); // [0, "C"]
console.log(enumValues(Test4)); // ["0", "C"]
console.log(enumValues(Test5)); // ["A"] 
console.log(enumValues(Test6)); // ["undefined"] 
console.log(enumValues(Test7)); // [0, "A"]
console.log(enumValues(Test8)); // ["A"]
console.log(enumValues(Test9)); // ["B", "A"]
```

[Online version.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdgVwLYGkIgM4B57IHxQC8sAHgMYA2CAJhFgNboD2AZrIkgDRQcBGEAJzwAoYWSZwMwKBA4B5XgCsIZacRwcZJYLOoYoAJRVMB1LFIEBLOAHNufQVAA+UC9Zt48ACggAudsgAlEQEAN7CUJFQ4pLS4mAgRFChAHRpEAC+UACG+qFQANooUNYBqOjYuEh4ALr+VUU1UBkA3BFRCsqqKQBu2VQQGD6BKSwmMNlkABZefQMhUKCQrFBzCNCEm1AA5A4C21AAZIdQtBQQOtFMCQVrEDWBbVFQAhcIAnBXCW2tojFSMg4aEwSQ0yC0OjgekMxlM5mAVls9mQ-AEzlcCPcnh89Q4wUIYXakVewHen06KmAKUYmB88iUlOGwVyZWBlQ4eAKNR+bTEEgBsmQADV+ut9OoqhDdPojOI4W4kTwUY4XAqPN4-GV8YTniSyYU0ik4BAAO5QADKFy8FO6dyGgqQNuATMCTRZDSqbLB1RqXJ5ogdUAAKoNgABGZJQACCSQARABhWPcABCcYAIrGMsJAyGpAAmSNRlPNbOaXPAADMhaSAAZi8QE7GSznQwAWasNmtJqCphuJ5tl0MAVkjCChEBY1gg1DjUabWZbUgAbB2oLGx7RJ8bqPPS+DywB2Qv1tdzgf70MADlXsbnJ9vu8XwAAnDfk93e6fd3zJExzikKCYGw6WQJ0vHLMNAkeKAAHoYOSKN-EbFMkIzLN-j-CAAKAkDHQZVRwNDPMoJaWD4NCRCoDrHt-DDdD+Uw7DgIdMDywrEiyIQ-xqOTJDE3o39-0A5j6S6Z1y1bDi4K4tcuxQtd+J-DBGOE3DWOHKTyI3Ccp2oJC5wE5ShJwlj8PE0Ml00mT13HLdp0zJSVJM0TGUPKyKO4zheK-QynJE0CzMIqRL3cyiH3kh9fOM-y8LEoKX1CpD3wigy-gY6LcLZeLIOg6SCnCtd3xqRyModLLy2I3L4Pyu9CtjYqMNKoEKni9iqsKArYyKkqsNUsqWokqyau7Lr6p6pjMoGjT2vy7S7J3Br0t65zkHKiyhofRbBOWmK1qkA8Ntq0atqMnbJtpcsQpmzrusas7+ou0Nn0OkbuvGvqOBFAYhggjbE24WMMxOvzcK+sV4sq0i8uosNgaa4VRUGVqhuoxs4fuz7EZ+tsNrkhSxruiaHTBpHyyHF6mnelakBJ7Hlw2ubdPqqAqZi2n4oOmbUbndGicx774quqHqs21nQax+Lnuu5KvxqIA)

Answer (score 15):

In TypeScript, an enum is compiled to a map (to get the value from the key) in javascript:

```
enum MyEnum {
  entry0,
  entry1,
}

console.log(MyEnum['entry0']); // 0
console.log(MyEnum['entry1']); // 1
```

It also creates a reversed map (to get the key from the value):

```
console.log(MyEnum[0]); // 'entry0'
console.log(MyEnum[0]); // 'entry1'
```

So you can access the name of an entry by doing:

```
console.log(MyEnum[MyEnum.entry0]); // 'entry0'
console.log(MyEnum[MyEnum.entry1]); // 'entry1'
```

---

However, **string enum has no reverse map by design** (see [comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21935#issuecomment-365562566) and [pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15486)) because this could lead to conflict between keys and values in the map object.

```
enum MyEnum {
  entry0 = 'value0',
  entry1 = 'value1',
}

console.log(MyEnum['value0']); // undefined
console.log(MyEnum['value1']); // undefined
```

If you want to force your string enum to compile a reversed map (you then have to make sure all the keys and values are different), you can use this trick:

```
enum MyEnum {
  entry0 = <any>'value0',
  entry1 = <any>'value1',
}

console.log(MyEnum['value0']); // 'entry0'
console.log(MyEnum['value1']); // 'entry1'
console.log(MyEnum[MyEnum.entry0]); // 'entry0'
console.log(MyEnum[MyEnum.entry1]); // 'entry1'
```

Comment: Nicely covered theory! The question asked for "get each enumerated symbol name" though.

Answer (score 13):

Assume you have an `enum`

```
export enum SCROLL_LABEL_OFFSET {
  SMALL = 48,
  REGULAR = 60,
  LARGE = 112
}
```

and you want to create a type based on enum but not just copy and paste.
You could use an `enum` to create your `type` like this:

```
export type ScrollLabelOffset = keyof typeof SCROLL_LABEL_OFFSET;
```

In result you will receive a `type` with possible values as `'SMALL' | 'REGULAR' | 'LARGE'`

Comment: But the question asked for a value, not for a type.

Answer (score 9):

Starting from TypeScript 2.4, the enum would not contain the key as a member anymore. [source from TypeScript readme](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#string-enums)

> The caveat is that string-initialized enums can't be reverse-mapped to get the original enum member name. In other words, you can't write Colors["RED"] to get the string "Red".

My solution:

```
export const getColourKey = (value: string ) => {
    let colourKey = '';
    for (const key in ColourEnum) {
        if (value === ColourEnum[key]) {
            colourKey = key;
            break;
        }
    }
    return colourKey;
};
```

Comment: Question asked for "get each enumerated symbol name". This finds a specific key by value.

Answer (score 7):

Based on some answers above I came up with this type-safe function signature:

```
export function getStringValuesFromEnum<T>(myEnum: T): (keyof T)[] {
  return Object.keys(myEnum).filter(k => typeof (myEnum as any)[k] === 'number') as any;
}
```

Usage:

```
enum myEnum { entry1, entry2 };
const stringVals = getStringValuesFromEnum(myEnum);
```

the type of `stringVals` is `'entry1' | 'entry2'`

[See it in action](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQMpQE4zMgNQEMAbEVAZwDFs4BbAUTBDoB4AVAPgAo6BPJiwBcidgEoR3ANao+cYKLEBtALqIA3gFgAUIkTZ0IbEgDyAIwBWqaADoZfCrwHM6Ym8BgkoqbNMQBeTkQoPgAHVHlEJ0E6RCIKOLA+ZSk1f3TEAHIXMx9MsTiEoiSAbh0AXx0dVBdEfhiNRBqcPgBGABomsBaAJkRysu0IBAooRFHcfGISBP8UdCxJwlJyalpGF2iXMUHhsAo4ElQbEjhkbgm8ZZmxIA)

Comment: The function should return ```(keyof T)[]``` instead of ```keyof T```. Also, the ```export``` stops your playground from working.

Comment: For `enum Test1 { A = "C", B = "D" }` returns `[]`.

Answer (score 7):

They have provided a concept called 'reverse-mapping' in their official documentation. It helped me:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings

The solution is quite straight forward:

```
enum Enum {
 A,
}

let a = Enum.A;
let nameOfA = Enum[a]; // "A"
```

Comment: This works, but *only* on **numeric** `enum`s.

Comment: Question asked for "get each enumerated symbol name".

Answer (score 6):

According to TypeScript documentation, we can do this via Enum with static functions.

Get Enum Name with static functions

```
enum myEnum { 
    entry1, 
    entry2 
}

namespace myEnum {
    export function GetmyEnumName(m: myEnum) {
      return myEnum[m];
    }
}


now we can call it like below
myEnum.GetmyEnumName(myEnum.entry1);
// result entry1
```

for reading more about Enum with static function follow the below link
https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/enums.html

Comment: This searches for enum key by value. Question asked for "get each enumerated symbol name".

Answer (score 6):

I wrote an EnumUtil class which is making a type check by the enum value:

```
export class EnumUtils {
  /**
   * Returns the enum keys
   * @param enumObj enum object
   * @param enumType the enum type
   */
  static getEnumKeys(enumObj: any, enumType: EnumType): any[] {
    return EnumUtils.getEnumValues(enumObj, enumType).map(value => enumObj[value]);
  }

  /**
   * Returns the enum values
   * @param enumObj enum object
   * @param enumType the enum type
   */
  static getEnumValues(enumObj: any, enumType: EnumType): any[] {
    return Object.keys(enumObj).filter(key => typeof enumObj[key] === enumType);
  }
}

export enum EnumType {
  Number = 'number',
  String = 'string'
}
```

How to use it:

```
enum NumberValueEnum{
  A= 0,
  B= 1
}

enum StringValueEnum{
  A= 'A',
  B= 'B'
}

EnumUtils.getEnumKeys(NumberValueEnum, EnumType.Number);
EnumUtils.getEnumValues(NumberValueEnum, EnumType.Number);

EnumUtils.getEnumKeys(StringValueEnum, EnumType.String);
EnumUtils.getEnumValues(StringValueEnum, EnumType.String);
```

Result for NumberValueEnum keys: ["A", "B"]

Result for NumberValueEnum values: [0, 1]

Result for StringValueEnumkeys: ["A", "B"]

Result for StringValueEnumvalues: ["A", "B"]

Comment: Nice! However, I would switch what you define as keys and values. Values should be what's to the right of the equals sign, keys on the left

Comment: How to use with heterogenous enums?

Answer (score 6):

There are already a lot of answers here but I figure I'll throw my solution onto the stack anyway.

**[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAggxnA9mEAXAKgTwA7CgbwFgAoKKAcUUQHMAbPAXigHJqrmAaEsgGUTgCGtKE2aDanblABiAuMABGVANYiWSxJNJR0AdwCWqVMABOa5gdRbe+kMuAATAJIhzt5cxIBfEqhx4AaWBMNXtMRAAzKD9cSNgEZDQsXCgAelSoIJCmACJKGnocqAAfKBy+cSLSnNl5DWUqsr1DYxNG8vdHFxySJBAAZ1QobAF9E0c1AAoAeQUAK2A4VAA6MP7J+CQUDH8ASigBfszggG0AXV3l8YcweUnJuTgOKDD9hgA+AilHk83EndwJzCZzOoWCUnGqDAJlcj28z3wXgORwASotECYHAAeP7bZLAZ6DEy2ajvXYkCnEPqDKDUYCoXFJfwAOQEEEYUEmMWAAC54lsmbg3p8iNpIdDXCMxo4Ttyzt4ANyU3qIAaIejLWg0SZ0hkJPEstnADb6wXAZa1RQqXa7IA)**

```
enum AccountType {
  Google = 'goo',
  Facebook = 'boo',
  Twitter = 'wit',
}

type Key = keyof typeof AccountType // "Google" | "Facebook" | "Twitter"

// this creates a POJO of the enum "reversed" using TypeScript's Record utility
const reversed = (Object.keys(AccountType) as Key[]).reduce((acc, key) => {
  acc[AccountType[key]] = key
  return acc
}, {} as Record<AccountType, string>)
```

For Clarity:

```
/*
 * reversed == {
 *   "goo": "Google",
 *   "boo": "Facebook",
 *   "wit": "Twitter",
 * }
 * reversed[AccountType.Google] === "Google" 
 */
```

Reference for [TypeScript Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt)

To iterate:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(reversed)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

A nice helper function:

```
const getAccountTypeName = (type: AccountType) => {
  return reversed[type]
};

// getAccountTypeName(AccountType.Twitter) === 'Twitter'
```

Comment: How does it "reverse" `enum Test8 { A = "A", B = "A" }`? The question asked for a way to "get each enumerated symbol name", i.e. for a list of keys.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph you're right, I didn't spell out how to iterate with `Object.entries`

Comment: I came here for the type: +1 for keyof typeof <ENUM>

Answer (score 6):

Having **numeric enum**:

```
enum MyNumericEnum {
 First = 1,
 Second = 2
}
```

You need to convert it to array first:

```
const values = Object.values(MyNumericEnum);
// ['First', 'Second', 1, 2]
```

As you see, it contains both keys and values. Keys go first.

After that, you can retrieve its keys:

```
values.slice(0, values.length / 2);
// ['First', 'Second']
```

And values:

```
values.slice(values.length / 2);
// [1, 2]
```

For **string enums**, you can use `Object.keys(MyStringEnum)` in order to get keys and `Object.values(MyStringEnum)` in order to get values respectively.

Though it's somewhat challenging to extract keys and values of **mixed enum**.

Comment: For numeric enum `enum Test { A = 0, B = -1 }` it produces `["A", 0]` as keys.

Comment: Yes, having negative value seems to break the usual order. In this case slice operation won't work and some sort of filtering has to be applied (may include regexp).

Comment: Having your example, it would be something like this:

`const enumValues = Object.values(Test);
const keys = enumValues.filter((value) => !(/^-?\d+$/.test(value)));
const values = enumValues.filter((value) => /^-?\d+$/.test(value));`

Answer (score 5):

The only solution that works for me in all cases *(even if values are strings)* is the following :

```
var enumToString = function(enumType, enumValue) {
    for (var enumMember in enumType) {
        if (enumType[enumMember]==enumValue) return enumMember
    }
}
```

Comment: This searches for enum key by value. Question asked for "get each enumerated symbol name".

Answer (score 5):

[typescript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=1&pln=21&pc=1#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-UHcch6UA)

```
enum TransactionStatus {
  SUBMITTED = 'submitted',
  APPROVED = 'approved',
  PAID = 'paid',
  CANCELLED = 'cancelled',
  DECLINED = 'declined',
  PROCESSING = 'processing',
}


let set1 = Object.entries(TransactionStatus).filter(([,value]) => value === TransactionStatus.SUBMITTED || value === TransactionStatus.CANCELLED).map(([key,]) => {
    return key
})


let set2 = Object.entries(TransactionStatus).filter(([,value]) => value === TransactionStatus.PAID || value === TransactionStatus.APPROVED).map(([key,]) => {
    return key
})

let allKeys = Object.keys(TransactionStatus)



console.log({set1,set2,allKeys})
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `enum-values` package I wrote when I had the same problem:

[Git: enum-values](https://github.com/slavik57/enum-values)

```
var names = EnumValues.getNames(myEnum);
```

Comment: You aren't really answering the question, it would be better to document your answer with code/etc but I did find the package useful.

Comment: Looks like the magic line is `Object.keys(e).filter(key => isNaN(+key))`, which will not work with string enums, etc, right?

Comment: @jchook it will work. You can look at this [test](https://github.com/slavik57/enum-values/blob/9a1ef046e394f5f8b55f1be5e5d76070ae6591a3/src/enumValues.test.ts#L44)

Comment: No, you can't, because it's buggy: for `enum Test { A = 0, B = NaN }` it returns `["A", "B", "NaN"]`.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph Yes this is an edge case, but not an interesting one. Who will ever define an enum like this? It is like arguing to not use '+' for adding numbers because when you pass it a string it concatenates instead of adding. As I see enums are keys mapped to either a string or a number. If you map it to a NaN, you are doing something wrong

Comment: Well, the only reason there is such an edge case is subpar programming practice. Current test is no better than `if (someBool.toString() === 'true')`: a random conversion that the problem never even needed.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph I don't see how an invalid input makes the code incorrect. Validation could be added, but I think for this case, it's not interesting because it never happens in real life programming

Answer (score 4):

I found this question by searching "TypeScript iterate over enum keys". So I just want to post solution which works for me in my case. Maybe it'll help to someone too.

My case is the following: I want to iterate over each enum key, then filter some keys, then access some object which has keys as computed values from enum. So this is how I do it without having any TS error.

```
    enum MyEnum = { ONE = 'ONE', TWO = 'TWO' }
    const LABELS = {
       [MyEnum.ONE]: 'Label one',
       [MyEnum.TWO]: 'Label two'
    }


    // to declare type is important - otherwise TS complains on LABELS[type]
    // also, if replace Object.values with Object.keys - 
    // - TS blames wrong types here: "string[] is not assignable to MyEnum[]"
    const allKeys: Array<MyEnum> = Object.values(MyEnum)

    const allowedKeys = allKeys.filter(
      (type) => type !== MyEnum.ONE
    )

    const allowedLabels = allowedKeys.map((type) => ({
      label: LABELS[type]
    }))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get an array of names from Enum in this way:

```
const enumNames: string[] = Object.keys(YourEnum).filter(key => isNaN(Number(key)));
```

Comment: For `enum Test { A = 0, B = NaN }` it returns `["A", "B", "NaN"]`.

Answer (score 4):

In case if you want to get the name in the html

For this enum

```
enum CanadianProvinces {
    AB,
    BC,
    MB,
    NB,
    NL,
    NT,
    NS,
    NU,
    ON,
    PE,
    QC,
    SK,
    YT
}
```

Assign a variable in your component as

```
canadianProvinces = CanadianProvinces
```

Then, in your html

```
{{canadianProvinces[0]}}
```

Comment: wicked sorcery!

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but, why do not use a `const` object map?

Instead of doing this:

```js
enum Foo {
    BAR = 60,
    EVERYTHING_IS_TERRIBLE = 80
}

console.log(Object.keys(Foo))
// -> ["60", "80", "BAR", "EVERYTHING_IS_TERRIBLE"]
console.log(Object.values(Foo))
// -> ["BAR", "EVERYTHING_IS_TERRIBLE", 60, 80]
```

Do this (pay attention to the `as const` cast):

```js
const Foo = {
    BAR: 60,
    EVERYTHING_IS_TERRIBLE: 80
} as const

console.log(Object.keys(Foo))
// -> ["BAR", "EVERYTHING_IS_TERRIBLE"]
console.log(Object.values(Foo))
// -> [60, 80]
```

Comment: Correct me if im wrong but `console.log(Object.keys(Foo))` in the first example only returns `["BAR", "EVERYTHING_IS_TERRIBLE"]`..

Comment: @Peter give a look [here at the ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAYg9nKBvAUFdUBCBBASlAXigDYAGAGjQwFEA1a3ATQBUAJASQDkBxAfXYDKvZg1ztMAGWqEoADlIoAvihQBjOCADOcADbAAdDrgBzABQB5AEYArYKoAu+gNbAAnptPw4ASm8ogA), just open the console and click on run. At least for me, it prints `["60", "80", "BAR", "EVERYTHING_IS_TERRIBLE"]`

Comment: it seems your right, the fun thing if you change from numbers to strings you get the output i expected, i have no idea why typescript handles string and numbers differently in enums..

Comment: Because the question asks specifically for a way to iterate over enum?

Answer (score 3):

If you have enum

```
enum Diet {
  KETO = "Ketogenic",
  ATKINS = "Atkins",
  PALEO = "Paleo",
  DGAF = "Whatever"
}
```

Then you can get key and values like:

```
Object.keys(Diet).forEach((d: Diet) => {
  console.log(d); // KETO
  console.log(Diet[d]) // Ketogenic
});
```

Comment: This causes an error:

`Argument of type '(d: Diet) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'd' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'MyEnum'.(2345)`

Comment: For `enum Test2 { A, B }` it shows `"0", "1", "A", "B"` as keys.

Answer (score 2):

I find that solution more elegant:

```
for (let val in myEnum ) {

 if ( isNaN( parseInt( val )) )
     console.log( val );
}
```

It displays:

```
bar 
foo
```

Comment: For `enum Test { A = 0, B = NaN }` produces `["A", "B", "NaN"]`.

Answer (score 2):

To get the list of the enum values you have to use:

```
enum AnimalEnum {
  DOG = "dog", 
  CAT = "cat", 
  MOUSE = "mouse"
}

Object.values(AnimalEnum);
```

Comment: It's sadly not working as expected for enum with int values

Comment: What is the result in the case of int values?

Comment: It will return the name of the enum AND the int value.
Example: `["DOG", "CAT", "MOUSE", 1, 2, 3] `

Answer (score 2):

I hope the question is still relevant. I use such functions:

```
function enumKeys(target: Record<string, number|string>): string[] {
  const allKeys: string[] = Object.keys(target);
  const parsedKeys: string[] = [];

  for (const key of allKeys) {
    const needToIgnore: boolean
      = target[target[key]]?.toString() === key && !isNaN(parseInt(key));

    if (!needToIgnore) {
      parsedKeys.push(key);
    }
  }

  return parsedKeys;
}

function enumValues(target: Record<string, number|string>): Array<string|number> {
  const keys: string[] = enumKeys(target);
  const values: Array<string|number> = [];

  for (const key of keys) {
    values.push(target[key]);
  }

  return values;
}
```

Example:

```
enum HttpStatus {
  OK,
  INTERNAL_ERROR,
  FORBIDDEN = 'FORBIDDEN',
  NOT_FOUND = 404,
  BAD_GATEWAY = 'bad-gateway'
}


console.log(enumKeys(HttpStatus));
// > ["OK", "INTERNAL_ERROR", "FORBIDDEN", "NOT_FOUND", "BAD_GATEWAY"] 

console.log(enumValues(HttpStatus));
// > [0, 1, "FORBIDDEN", 404, "bad-gateway"]
```

Comment: I'm using TS 3.7.1 and it gives TS errors for the parsedKeys and values vars. This can be fixed by typing out the values variable as `Array<string | number>` and the parsedKeys variable as `string[]`.

Comment: @YulricSequeira Thank you! Updated types for variables' initialization.

Comment: `isNaN(parseInt(key)` is otherwise called `typeof key !== 'number'`. Convering a number to string and then back to number just to check that it's really a number is not smart.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph Not quite so. `isNaN(parseInt(key)` gives more information, such as whether the string is a numeric string.

Answer (score 2):

This would work more efficiently for key-value based enum:

```
enum yourEnum {
  ["First Key"] = "firstWordValue",
  ["Second Key"] = "secondWordValue"
}

Object.keys(yourEnum)[Object.values(yourEnum).findIndex(x => x === yourValue)]
// Result for passing values as yourValue
// FirstKey
// SecondKey
```

Comment: What is `yourValue`? Question is to "get each enumerated symbol name".

Answer (score 2):

Can be short and simple:

```js
enum AnimalEnum {
  DOG = "dog", 
  CAT = "cat", 
  MOUSE = "mouse"
}

Object.keys(AnimalEnum).filter(v => typeof v == 'string' && isNaN(v))
```

Comment: For `enum Test { A = 0, B = NaN }` produces `["A", "B", "NaN"]`.

Comment: ```let filteredKeys = Object.entries(AnimalEnum).filter(([,value]) => value === AnimalEnum.DOG || value === AnimalEnum.CAT).map(([key,]) => {
    return key
})```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following, which I think is shortest, cleanest and fastest:

```
Object.entries(test).filter(([key]) => (!~~key && key !== "0"))
```

Given the following mixed type enum definition:

```
enum testEnum {
  Critical = "critical",
  Major = 3,
  Normal = "2",
  Minor = "minor",
  Info = "info",
  Debug = 0
};
```

It will get transpire to the following:

```js
var testEnum = { 
  Critical: 'critical', 
  Major: 3,
  Normal: "2",
  Minor: 'minor',
  Info: "info",
  Debug: 0,
  [0]: "critical",
  [1]: 3,
  [2]: "2",
  [3]: "minor",
  [4]: "info",
  [5]: 0
}

function safeEnumEntries(test) {
    return Object.entries(test).filter(([key]) => (!~~key && key !== "0"));
};

console.log(safeEnumEntries(testEnum));
```

After executing the function, you will get **only** the **good** entries:

```
[
  ["Critical", "critical"],
  ["Major", 3],
  ["Normal", "2"],
  ["Minor", "minor"],
  ["Info", "info"],
  ["Debug", 0]
]
```

Comment: For `enum Test { A = 0, B = NaN }` returns `["A", "B", "NaN"]`.

Comment: Also it's not "cleanest", it's "clever", which is [regarded as antipattern](https://www.simplethread.com/dont-be-clever/).

Answer (score 1):

My Enum is like this:

```
export enum UserSorting {
    SortByFullName = "Sort by FullName", 
    SortByLastname = "Sort by Lastame", 
    SortByEmail = "Sort by Email", 
    SortByRoleName = "Sort by Role", 
    SortByCreatedAt = "Sort by Creation date", 
    SortByCreatedBy = "Sort by Author", 
    SortByUpdatedAt = "Sort by Edit date", 
    SortByUpdatedBy = "Sort by Editor", 
}
```

so doing this return *undefined*:

```
UserSorting[UserSorting.SortByUpdatedAt]
```

To resolve this issue, I choose another way to do it using a Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'enumKey'
})
export class EnumKeyPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value, args: string[] = null): any {
    let enumValue = args[0];
    var keys = Object.keys(value);
    var values = Object.values(value);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      if (values[i] == enumValue) {
        return keys[i];
      }
    }
    return null;
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
return this.enumKeyPipe.transform(UserSorting, [UserSorting.SortByUpdatedAt]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly answer of your question but it is a trick to tackle your problem.

```
export module Gender {

  export enum Type {
    Female = 1,
    Male = 2
  };

  export const List = Object.freeze([
    Type[Type.Female] ,
    Type[Type.Male]
  ]);

}
```

You can extend your list model in a way you want.

```
export const List = Object.freeze([
    { name: Type[Type.Female], value: Type.Female } ,
    { name: Type[Type.Male], value: Type.Male }
  ]);
```

Now, you can use it in this way:

```
for(const gender of Gender.List){
  console.log(gender.name);
  console.log(gender.value);
}
```

or:

```
if(i === Gender.Type.Male){
  console.log("I am a man.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a helper function to enumerate an enum:

```
static getEnumValues<T extends number>(enumType: {}): T[] {
  const values: T[] = [];
  const keys = Object.keys(enumType);
  for (const key of keys.slice(0, keys.length / 2)) {
    values.push(<T>+key);
  }
  return values;
}
```

Usage:

```
for (const enumValue of getEnumValues<myEnum>(myEnum)) {
  // do the thing
}
```

The function returns something that can be easily enumerated, and also casts to the enum type.

Comment: For `enum Test1 { A = "C", B = "D" }` returns `[NaN]`.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few answers here and considering I looked it up despite this being 7 years old question, I surmise many more will come here. Here's my solution, which is a bit simpler than other ones, it handles numeric-only/text-only/mixed value enums, all the same.

```
enum funky {
    yum , tum='tum', gum = 'jump', plum = 4
}

const list1 = Object.keys(funky)
  .filter(k => (Number(k).toString() === Number.NaN.toString()));
console.log(JSON.stringify(list1)); // ["yum","tum","gum","plum"]" 

 // for the numeric enum vals (like yum = 0, plum = 4), typescript adds val = key implicitly (0 = yum, 4 = plum)
 // hence we need to filter out such numeric keys (0 or 4)
```

Comment: The thing you cherished the most betrayed you: for `enum Test { A = 0, B = NaN }` it returns `["A", "B", "NaN"]`.

Answer (score 0):

My humble 2 cents based on reading an awesome comment from [github TS discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42457#issuecomment-788751625)

```
const EnvironmentVariants = ['development', 'production', 'test'] as const 
type EPredefinedEnvironment = typeof EnvironmentVariants[number]
```

Then at compile time:

```
// TS2322: Type '"qaEnv"' is not assignable to type '"development" | "production" | "test"'.
const qaEnv: EPredefinedEnvironment = 'qa'
```

at runtime:

```
function isPredefinedEnvironemt(env: string) {
  for (const predefined of EnvironmentVariants) {
    if (predefined === env) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}

assert(isPredefinedEnvironemet('test'), true)
assert(isPredefinedEnvironemet('qa'), false)
```

Note, that `for(const index in EnvironmentVariants) {...}` will iterate over "0", "1", "2" set

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **typed** utility function which extracts enum names and values:

```
type Enum = { [key: string]: number | string };

function *enumNamesAndValues<E extends Enum>(e: E): Iterable<[keyof E, E[keyof E]]> {
    for (const key in e) {
        const value = e[key];
        if (typeof value === "number")
            yield [key, value];
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
enum ETestEnum {
    Foo,
    Bar,
    Baz
}

const namesAndValues = [...enumNamesAndValues(ETestEnum)];

console.log(namesAndValues);
```

This prints:

```
[["Foo", 0], ["Bar", 1], ["Baz", 2]]
```

Note that the type of `namesAndValues` is `["Foo" | "Bar" | "Baz", ETestEnum][]`.

---

Extracting only names or only values can be accomplished analogously:

```
function *enumNames<E extends Enum>(e: E): Iterable<keyof E> {
    for (const key in e) {
        const value = e[key];
        if (typeof value === "number")
            yield key;
    }
}

function *enumValues<E extends Enum>(e: E): Iterable<E[keyof E]> {
    for (const key in e) {
        const value = e[key];
        if (typeof value === "number")
            yield value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using a current version TypeScript you can use functions like these to map the Enum to a record of your choosing. Note that you cannot define string values with these functions as they look for keys with a value that is a number.

```
enum STATES {
  LOGIN,
  LOGOUT,
}

export const enumToRecordWithKeys = <E extends any>(enumeration: E): E => (
  Object.keys(enumeration)
    .filter(key => typeof enumeration[key] === 'number')
    .reduce((record, key) => ({...record, [key]: key }), {}) as E
);

export const enumToRecordWithValues = <E extends any>(enumeration: E): E => (
  Object.keys(enumeration)
    .filter(key => typeof enumeration[key] === 'number')
    .reduce((record, key) => ({...record, [key]: enumeration[key] }), {}) as E
);

const states = enumToRecordWithKeys(STATES)
const statesWithIndex = enumToRecordWithValues(STATES)

console.log(JSON.stringify({
  STATES,
  states,
  statesWithIndex,
}, null ,2));

// Console output:
{
  "STATES": {
    "0": "LOGIN",
    "1": "LOGOUT",
    "LOGIN": 0,
    "LOGOUT": 1
  },
  "states": {
    "LOGIN": "LOGIN",
    "LOGOUT": "LOGOUT"
  },
  "statesWithIndex": {
    "LOGIN": 0,
    "LOGOUT": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: `.reduce((accum, key) => ({...accum, [key]: ... }), {})` is an antipattern with `O(N^2)` complexity. Don't use this code.

Comment: For `enum Test1 { A = "C", B = "D" }` the result of `enumToRecordWithKeys` is `{}`.

Answer (score -1):

If it's your `enum` and you define as seen below, names and values are the same, it'll give you the entries' names directly.

```
enum myEnum { 
    entry1="entry1", 
    entry2="entry2"
 }

for (var entry in myEnum) { 
    // use entry's name here, e.g., "entry1"
}
```

Comment: No, they're not? Try `enum Test3 { A = 0, B = "C" }`.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph I think you missed my `if condition `. :)