# Looping through an enum, TypeScript and JQuery

Tags: jquery, enums, typescript, ienumerable, enumeration

Hello im trying t develop a straight forward todo app using TypeScript and JQuery. I have an enum that lists task types:

```
export enum TaskType { FrontEnd, BackEnd, Designer };
```

However looping through the emum using jquery.each or for loop, i get the following result, (values then indexes):

```
        FrontEnd, BackEnd, Designer, 0, 1, 2
```

The following is the code i loop through the enum:

```
        constructor(e?: Object) {             

            var template = this.FormTemplate;

            $(e).append(template);

            var sel = template.find('select');

            /*$.each(TaskType, function (index, el) {
                sel.append("<option value='" + index + "'>" + el + "</option>");
            });*/

            for(var i=0; i < (typeof TaskType).length; i++){
                sel.append("<option value='" + TaskType[i] + "'>" + TaskType[i] + "</option>");
            }

        }
```

Can someone tell me why this is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one get the names of TypeScript enum entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111657/how-does-one-get-the-names-of-typescript-enum-entries)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

TypeScript enums when compiled into plain JS contain both the symbolic name AND the numeric values as properties and that explains why you get `FrontEnd, BackEnd, Designer, 0, 1, 2` when you try to enumerate the properties of the object.  As best I know, there is no post-compile way to enumerate only the symbolic names.  You could enumerate all of them and skip anything that is a number.

From [this article](https://tusksoft.com/blog/posts/11/const-enums-in-typescript-1-4-and-how-they-differ-from-standard-enums), you can see exactly how a TypeScript enum compiles into JS.

If you have this TypeScript:

```
//TypeScript declaration:
enum StandardEnum {FirstItem, SecondItem, ThirdItem};
```

It compiles to this Javscript:

```
//Compiled javascript:
var StandardEnum;
(function (StandardEnum) {
    StandardEnum[StandardEnum["FirstItem"] = 0] = "FirstItem";
    StandardEnum[StandardEnum["SecondItem"] = 1] = "SecondItem";
    StandardEnum[StandardEnum["ThirdItem"] = 2] = "ThirdItem";
})(StandardEnum || (StandardEnum = {}));
;
```

Which is essentially this result:

```
var StandardEnum = {
    "FirstItem": 0,
    "SecondItem": 1,
    "ThirdItem": 2,
    "0": "FirstItem",
    "1": "SecondItem",
    "2": "ThirdItem"
};
```

So, unless you specifically ignore the numeric properties, there is no way to enumerate just the enum names.

You could do that like this:

```
 for (var item in StandardEnum) {
     if (StandardEnum.hasOwnProperty(item) && !/^\d+$/.test(item)) {
         console.log(item);
     }
 }
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/65cfg88u/

---

FYI, if what you really want is:

```
var StandardEnum = {
    "FirstItem": 0,
    "SecondItem": 1,
    "ThirdItem": 2
};
```

Then, maybe you should not use the enum and just use this standard JS declaration.  Then, you could get the properties with `Object.keys(StandardEnum)`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but wouldn't it make sense to return it as key:value object?, this is a big let down, anyway i ended up using : if(TaskType[i] !== undefined) in for loop since it returns values then undefined values.

Comment: @meji - you can return whatever you want - I was just showing you how you could identify only the named properties.  FYI, maybe you should just define a JS object with properties rather than an enum if that's what you want it to be.

Comment: Does this also apply for typescript@2?

Comment: @k0pernikus - I don't have any reason to believe it has changed in TS2.0, but have not explicitly examined TS2.0 output in this regard.

Comment: How about something like `Object.values(myEnum).filter(isNaN)` to get an array of non-number values?

Comment: @mightyiam - It's possible that would work for this specific case, but it could depend upon what the enum values were because of special cases.  I don't like relying on automatic type coercion and the coercion rules for `isNan()` are quite complicated [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#Description).