# angular reactive form: pass child component value to parent component

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

im implementing reactive-form in angular. im unable to pass value from child to parent.

example parent form:

```
<div class="fields-wrap" [formGroup]="parent">
<div class="input-wrap">
  <child-component></child-component>
</div>
<input type"button">Submit</div>
</div>
```

Child componet form:

```
<div class="fields-wrap" [formGroup]="child">
<input type="text" formControlName="firstname" />
<input type="text" formControlName="lastname" />
<input type="text" formControlName="email" />
</div>
```

how to get these child value when i click submit from parent component. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of passing in `Form` as an `@Input()` you can use `viewProviders` which I find it a lot more cleaner to read.

To do this is very simple, in your child component typescript file you just need to add one property to your `@Component`

```
viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective }]
```

So all together it would output like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss'],
  viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective }]
})
```

Example on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ruxfee

Comment: I like this approach. What if address `FormGroup` needs to be created in the address.component? Does this idea somehow apply to this situation?

Comment: You mean you want the `address: this.formBuilder.group({...})` inside `address.component.ts`? Not sure if possible unless somehow you are able to get reference of the `form`, could be through `@Input`? I haven't tried if you are doing that then no point of doing this method. Ideally you want your components to be dumb as possible and have your main component act as a "container" which handles events from the dumb component. Making component architecture reusable.

Comment: It actually works via `@Input`, so it seems that I will stick to this solution, thx.