# validating a child component on submit

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I've been looking through the internet and couldn't find any answer.

I'm using angular 10 and reactive forms.

Here is my problem: Clicking on submit button triggers validity on my form on the button level but not at a child component level

Here is the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m6aksy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts)

if you press "save" in this example you'll see only the first input triggers validation and goes red whereas the other needs to be manually clicked on. I'm having a `formGroup` with 2 controls, 1 is a `FormControl` and the other one a `FormArray`. I pass the main `formGroup` to the child component and push 1 `formGroup` inside the `formArray`, this `formGroup` has one `formControl`. So basically I have at the leaf two `FormControl`. please tell me if that don't make sense.

So instead I would like validity for all of the elements to be checked, weither it is inside a child component or not.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ControlContainer` in `viewProviders` like this:

`control-container.ts`

```
import { Provider, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlContainer } from '@angular/forms';

export function controlProviderFactory(container: ControlContainer) {
  return container;
}

export const CONTROL_CONTAINER: Provider = {
  provide: ControlContainer,
  useFactory: controlProviderFactory,
  deps: [[new SkipSelf(), ControlContainer]],
};
```

`child.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { CONTROL_CONTAINER } from "../control-container";

@Component({
  selector: "app-child",
  templateUrl: "./child.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./child.component.css"],
  viewProviders: [CONTROL_CONTAINER]
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() public form: FormGroup;

  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

`child.component.html`

```
<ng-container formArrayName="subForm">
    <mat-input-container [formGroupName]="0">
    <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput formControlName="subControl">
    </mat-form-field>
    </mat-input-container>
</ng-container>
```

And initialize in constructor of `AppComponent`:

```
  constructor (private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.fg = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [null, Validators.required],
      subForm: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });

    const control = <FormArray>this.fg.controls['subForm'];

    control.push(this.formBuilder.group({
      subControl: ['', Validators.required]
    }));
  }
```

There is an error "mat-error does not display on submit when fields are added in a FormArray". It's described on GitHub [here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/9007).

Working example based on your code you can find [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ymhmxk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Thanks this is great! can you add a bit more of an explanation reagarding the control container object. I'll implement that and mark as answered if this works

Comment: I've made few changes in order to initialise the formArray in the child component and it worked. Great!!!

Answer (score 4):

Angular doesn't have a mechanism to auto-validate all form controls and sub-form controls, that task is left for the developer:

```
  save() {
    this.validateAllFormFields(this.fg);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.fg = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(
        { value: "", disabled: false },
        Validators.required
      ),
      sub: new FormArray([])
    });
  }

  validateAllFormFields(formGroup: FormGroup | FormArray) {
    Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(field => {
      const control = formGroup.get(field);
      if (control instanceof FormControl) {
        control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
      } else if (control instanceof FormGroup || control instanceof FormArray) {
        this.validateAllFormFields(control);
      }
    });
  }
```

- [demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-validate-all-nested-form-fields?file=src/app/app.component.ts)
- [article with more explanation](https://loiane.com/2017/08/angular-reactive-forms-trigger-validation-on-submit/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, What do you think about the `controlValueAccessor` method of @transformer?

Comment: the custom controlValueAccessor approach would work if the sub-form has direct FormControls (i.e no deeply nested controls), the solution I provided is for a general purpose usecase

Comment: ok @karavanjo seemed the best solution, even though I'm not understanding everything. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Can't you just call formGroup.markAllAsTouched() instead of looping over every FormControl?

Answer (score 0):

For a sue case, lets say you have dashboard with child widgets scenario

1. This [NGX-Sub-Form](https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form) works well as a turnkey, I like this approach because it breaks up the complexity as [a second/level sub form](https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form#second-component-level-optional) simply by extending one the 4 classes/options

---

2. Angular recommended [approach of parent child interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild)

Below example [borrowed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45440487/6085193) from penley chan

```
@Directive({
selector: '[provide-parent-form]',
providers: [
    {
        provide: ControlContainer,
        useFactory: function (form: NgForm) {
            return form;
        },
        deps: [NgForm]
    }
  ]
})
export class ProvideParentForm {}
```

Usage: In your component at the root element before you have [(ngModel)] add the directive. Example:

```
<div provide-parent-form> 
   <input name="myInput" [(ngModel)]="myInput"> 
</div>
```

Now if you output your form object in your console or whatever you can see your component's controls under controls property of your form's object.

Comment: thank you for this answer but I've already wen't through this example, your example uses `ngForm` I use reactive form. any idea?

Comment: ahh i see, I have something will post tomorrow, but in the meantime here is an example. https://indepth.dev/posts/1245/angular-nested-reactive-forms-using-controlvalueaccessors-cvas there the icontrolAccessorValidator... don't exactly recall thats the key

Comment: thanks you I'll check that and be waiting for your answser