# How do you type an enum variable in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

I saw that in various stackoverflow answers on how to access an enum in html says to define a variable on the component and set it equal to the enum, like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835984/how-to-use-a-typescript-enum-value-in-an-angular2-ngswitch-statement). But, what would be the type?

To use their example:

```
enum MyEnum{
  First,
  Second
}

export class MyComponent{
  MyEnum = MyEnum;
  myEnumVar:MyEnum = MyEnum.Second
  ...
}

<div [ngSwitch]="myEnumVar">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="MyEnum.First"><app-first-component></app-first-component></div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="MyEnum.Second"><app-second-component></app-second-component></div>
  <div *ngSwitchDefault>MyEnumVar {{myEnumVar}} is not handled.</div>
</div>
```

`myEnumVar` was typed, but `MyEnum` was not. What am I supposed to type it as?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because enums are created as plain `{}`, their type is actually `object`.

For instance, the enum:

```
enum MyEnum{
  First,
  Second
}
```

is [**transpiled** to](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20MyEnum%7B%0D%0A%20%20First%2C%0D%0A%20%20Second%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%2F%2F%20declaration%20using%20type%0D%0Alet%20foo%3AObject%20%3D%20MyEnum%3B):

```
var MyEnum;
(function (MyEnum) {
    MyEnum[MyEnum["First"] = 0] = "First";
    MyEnum[MyEnum["Second"] = 1] = "Second";
})(MyEnum || (MyEnum = {}));
           // ^^^^^^^^^^^ --- important part
```

Notice `MyEnum` is, in the end, an object (`{}`) with added properties later. More specifically, with `number` keys and `string` values (see more below).

So, if you wish to declare a type, you have some alternatives.

For starters, you can use `object` or `any`, like below (but check the other alternatives as well):

```
export class MyComponent{
  MyEnum:Object = MyEnum;
  myEnumVar:MyEnum = MyEnum.Second
  ...
}
```

## Index signature type

Another option, for enums, you can also use the type 
`{[s: number]: number | string}`:

```
export class MyComponent{
  MyEnum:{[s: number]: number | string} = MyEnum;
  myEnumVar:MyEnum = MyEnum.Second
  ...
}
```

## `typeof`

Or, as [pointed by Gerrit0 (see their answer for the full info and due credits)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49737083/1850609):

```
export class MyComponent{
  MyEnum:typeof MyEnum = MyEnum;
  myEnumVar:MyEnum = MyEnum.Second
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer @acdcjunior , it worked. Do you mind breaking down what `{ [s: number]: string }` means? Why is it not reversed, like `{[s: string]: number}`, because enums are numbers with strings as keys?

Comment: A couple notes - 1. Don't use `Object`, use `object` instead. [Docs](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html). 2. `typeof Enum` is more correct than the indexed type.

Comment: @Gerrit0 Thanks for the answer and the comment. I have updated it to keep it accurate. (Guess that's what I'm supposed to do in these cases...)

Comment: @evereveron Yes, structurally, that's what enums are, objects with numbers as keys (although they have strings as keys too O_o) and numbers/strings as values.

Answer (score 3):

While acdcjunior's answer is technically correct - yes, an enum is an object, and yes it can be described with the `{[s: number]: string}` type, this is not how you should type the `MyEnum` property.

An enum contains both string and number values, so at the very least the index signature should be `{ [s: number]: string | number }` - `MyEnum[1] === "First"` while `MyEnum.First === 1`.

However, TypeScript provides a better way of doing this, the `typeof` operator. This is different from JavaScript's `typeof` - when you use `typeof` in a type declaration, it gets the type of a value and is not constrained to primitives and `object`.

To highlight the difference, here's an example:

```ts
enum MyEnum {
  First,
  Second
}

class MyComponent {
  static MyEnum: typeof MyEnum = MyEnum
  static MyObjectEnum: { [s: number]: string | number } = MyEnum
}

// a is `any`
// can't use MyComponent.MyObjectEnum.First
let a = MyComponent.MyObjectEnum['First']
// b is `MyEnum`
let b = MyComponent.MyEnum['First'] // or MyComponent.MyEnum.First
// c is `any`
let c = MyComponent.MyObjectEnum['Third']
// d is `any`
// using MyComponent.MyEnum.Third catches this error
let d = MyComponent.MyEnum['Third']
// neither catch this error
// e is type `string`
// f is type `string | number`
let e = MyComponent.MyEnum[3]
let f = MyComponent.MyObjectEnum[3]
```

If you look at the type inferred by your IDE when trying to type something, you can learn a lot about what types should be used.

[image: intellisense]