# How to iterate object keys using *ngFor?

Tags: angular, typescript, object, ngfor

I've been digging around, and found out that I can use the following to use *ngFor over an object:

```
 <div *ngFor="#obj of objs | ObjNgFor">...</div>
```

where `ObjNgFor` pipe is:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'ObjNgFor',  pure: false })
export class ObjNgFor implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args: any[] = null): any {
        return Object.keys(value).map(key => value[key]);
    }
}
```

However, when I have an object like this:

```
{
"propertyA":{
    "description":"this is the propertyA",
    "default":"sth"
 },
"propertyB":{
    "description":"this is the propertyB",
    "default":"sth"
 }
}
```

I am not quite sure how I can extract 'propertyA' and 'propertyB', so that it is accessible from the *ngFor directive. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

What I want to do, is to present the following HTML:

```
        <div *ngFor="#obj of objs | ObjNgFor" class="parameters-container">
            <div class="parameter-desc">
                {{SOMETHING}}:{{obj.description}}
            </div>
        </div>
```

Where something would be equal to `propertyA` and `propertyB` (this is how the object is structured). So, this would lead to:

```
propertyA:this is the propertyA
propertyB:this is the propertyB
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Update

In **6.1.0-beta.1** `KeyValuePipe` was introduced https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/24319

```
<div *ngFor="let item of {'b': 1, 'a': 1} | keyvalue">
  {{ item.key }} - {{ item.value }}
</div>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/eIfgvtsd66ztkDN2Xzio?p=preview&preview)**

**Previous version**

You could try something like this

```
export class ObjNgFor implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args: any[] = null): any {
        return Object.keys(value).map(key => Object.assign({ key }, value[key]));
    }
}
```

And then on your template

```
  <div *ngFor="let obj of objs | ObjNgFor">
   {{obj.key}} - {{obj.description}}
  </div>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TyPRMWKzvxOzjNlRClKj?p=preview)

Comment: The key value pipe is sorting out by the order of the keys and values orders in angular 6. How can we disable that ?

Answer (score 17):

Or instead of creating a pipe and passing an object to *ngFor, just pass `Object.keys(MyObject)` to *ngFor. It returns the same as the pipe, but without the hassle.

On TypeScript file:

```
let list = Object.keys(MyObject); // good old javascript on the rescue
```

On template (html):

```
*ngFor="let item of list"
```

Comment: Thank you!!! This made it look simple. You should add what to put on the template part btw =)

Comment: neat solution. I got the number values and the string values in the list though so I used the slice method to get the proper side of the array: options.slice(options.length / 2). Found this solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38554562/how-can-i-use-ngfor-to-iterate-over-typescript-enum-as-an-array-of-strings#38554683

Answer (score 14):

Just return the keys from the pipe instead of the values and then use the keys to access the values:

(`let` instead of `#` in the beta.17)

```ts
@Pipe({ name: 'ObjNgFor',  pure: false })
export class ObjNgFor implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args: any[] = null): any {
        return Object.keys(value)//.map(key => value[key]);
    }
}
```

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    pipes: [ObjNgFor],
    template: `
    <h1>Hello</h1>
 <div *ngFor="let key of objs | ObjNgFor">{{key}}:{{objs[key].description}}</div>    `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  objs = {
    "propertyA":{
      "description":"this is the propertyA",
      "default":"sth"
    },
    "propertyB":{
      "description":"this is the propertyB",
      "default":"sth"
    }
  };
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/tqxXV1?p=preview)

See also [Select based on enum in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35750059/select-based-on-enum-in-angular2/35750252#35750252)

Comment: Gunter - I would like to show user either 'propertyA' or 'propertyB'. So I need to change the pipe somehow

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Depending no what criteria do you want to show one or the other?

Comment: Not sure what exact use case you have in mind but I don't see why anything would not work with nested objects.

Comment: Can this be coupled with `async` pipe if  `objs` is asynchronous?

Comment: Sure `{{someObservable | async | ObjNgFor}}`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer how I can access to object value in asynchronous case with this approach ?

Answer (score 2):

**keys.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'keys' })
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(obj: Object, args: any[] = null): any {
        let array = [];
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
            array.push({
                value: obj[key],
                key: key
            });
        });
        return array;
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { KeysPipe } from './keys.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
    KeysPipe
  ]
})
```

**example.component.html**

```
<elem *ngFor="let item of obj | keys" id="{{ item.key }}">
    {{ item.value }}
</elem>
```

Answer (score -2):

no use pipes this it example

```
*ngFor="let Value bof Values; let i = index"

{{i}}
```

Comment: Complete code would be helpful instead of part of it.