# How can I use ngFor to iterate over Typescript Enum as an array of strings

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm using Angular2 and TypeScript and I have an enum:

```js
export enum Role {
    ServiceAdmin, CompanyAdmin, Foreman, AgentForeman, 
    CrewMember, AgentCrewMember, Customer
}
```

I want to use *ngFor to iterate over the enum. What is the best way to do this? Must I create a Pipe? Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Please, consider updating the accepted answer to Murolack's one as it is the easiest and most up-to-date one. Thanks!

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You can just use the "keyvalue" pipe introduced in Angular 6.1.

```html
<p *ngFor="let enum of TestEnum | keyvalue">
  {{ enum.key }} - {{ enum.value}}
</p>
```

See here for a full example ->
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gujg2e

Comment: It worked but sorted the order of the enum alphabetically.

Comment: @RRaj you can control sort order: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52794221/5253897

Comment: This doesn't work for me, as angular iterates through every key and every value for me... The functionality must've been modified in later versions... :(

Comment: Keep in mind that you can't use the enum directly like this with TestEnum, you have to set the enum to a variable like: public testEnum = TestEnum; Then in your loop you can use let enum of testEnum | keyvalue

Comment: @fonzane, it seems that as enums are default numeric, then ts maps k/v pairs for names and values; and values and names (for indexing, I guess)...  To solve this, I mapped my (string) enums to a value: `enum Food { Chips = 'chips', Fish = 'fish' }`, which solved the problem.  Far beter details here, https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/names-of-enums-typescript/

Comment: It works. But You should pay attention your enum's values. If the enum's values are number, The result will not be as You expected(2 times iteration happens)

Comment: a workaround to avoid double iteration:
`<p *ngFor="let enum of TestEnum | keyvalue; let i = index; let max = count;">
  <span *ngIf="i < max / 2">{{ enum.key }} - {{ enum.value}}</span>
</p>`

Answer (score 115):

An enum is just an object.

Your enum is written something like this in JavaScript:

```typescript
{
    0: "ServiceAdmin", 
    1: "CompanyAdmin", 
    2: "Foreman", 
    3: "AgentForeman", 
    4: "CrewMember", 
    5: "AgentCrewMember", 
    6: "Customer", 
    ServiceAdmin: 0, 
    CompanyAdmin: 1, 
    Foreman: 2, 
    AgentForeman: 3, 
    CrewMember: 4,
    AgentCrewMember: 5,
    Customer: 6
}
```

So you can iterate it this way ([plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ebz3bK6n83HRyNqOiMEe?p=preview)):

```typescript
@Component({
    ...
    template: `
    <div *ngFor="let item of keys()">
      {{ item }}
    </div>  
  `
})
export class YourComponent {
    role = Role;
    keys() : Array<string> {
        var keys = Object.keys(this.role);
        return keys.slice(keys.length / 2);
    }
}
```

Or **would be better to create custom pipe**:

```typescript
@Pipe({
  name: 'enumToArray'
})
export class EnumToArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(data: Object) {
    const keys = Object.keys(data);
    return keys.slice(keys.length / 2);
  }
}
```

**[Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/XpKqpMjxjZvUNKDxRxLS)**

**Update**

Typescript 2.4 allows enum members to contain string initializers like:

```typescript
enum Colors {
    Red = "RED",
    Green = "GREEN",
    Blue = "BLUE",
}
```

in this case you can just return `Object.keys(data);` from pipe.

Comment: this is not well working if having negative values included. btw: the plnkr is not working anymore.

Comment: @MA-Maddin Updated plunker

Comment: If anyone is using the custom pipe in a Shared Module, don't forget to add EnumToArrayPipe in exports

Comment: In angular 6 you can just return the array of keys and you don't have to slice half of them of in the Pipe: `return Object.keys(data);`

Comment: In fact in Angular 6 you don't even need the pipe anymore, just use `role = Object.keys(Role)` in your component.

Answer (score 17):

The scope of the template is the component instance. If you want to access something outside this scope you need to make it available from withing your component instance:

This also works if the enum keys do not start with 0

```ts
@Pipe({name: 'enumToArray'})
export class EnumToArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value) : Object {
    return Object.keys(value).filter(e => !isNaN(+e)).map(o => { return {index: +o, name: value[o]}});
  }
}

@Component({
  ...
  imports: [EnumsToArrayPipe],
  template: `<div *ngFor="let item of roles | enumToArray">{{item.index}}: {{item.name}}</div>`
})
class MyComponent {
  roles = Role;
}
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/35750252/217408

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just tried this but get the error "NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."  So it looks like I could create a pipe to tranform roles to an array of enums or strings. But it seems to me like I ought to be able to do this natively somehow.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the pipe. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Better solution than the cast to Array :-)

Comment: I get the error
Argument of type '{ imports: (typeof EnumToArrayPipe)[]; selector: string; templateUrl: string; styleUrls: string[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'imports' does not exist in type 'Component'.
When I put it in imports in the ngModule, it can't find the pipe. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: That's an old answer. Several things have changed since. Create a module and add the pipe to `declarations: [EnumToArrayPipe], `  and add the module to `imports: [...]` of every module where you want to use the pipe. The answer I linked to above shows how.

Comment: Using / referencing the pipe must be done with enum(s)ToArray as can be seen in the declaration of the pipe (name). I made the edit.

Answer (score 9):

I needed to do the same thing and maybe this is what you wanted.
More DRY and it can be used with `module` too.

```js
export enum Role {
    ServiceAdmin, CompanyAdmin, Foreman, AgentForeman, 
    CrewMember, AgentCrewMember, Customer
}

export namespace Role {

  export function keys(): Array<string>{
    var keys = Object.keys(Role);
    return keys.slice(keys.length / 2, keys.length-1);
  }
}
```

the object output before the slice

```
{
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "5",
    "6",
    "7",
    "ServiceAdmin",
    "CompanyAdmin",
    "Foreman",
    "AgentForeman",
    "CrewMember",
    "AgentCrewMember",
    "Customer",
    "keys"
}
```

typescript merges the two declarations hence the `keys.lenght-1`

and the `ngFor`:

```
<div *ngFor="let role of Roles.keys()">{{ role }}</div>
```

more info:
[Typescript's Declaration merging](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)

based on:
[TypeScript: Add functions to an Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150739/typescript-add-functions-to-an-enum)
https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/enums.html (at the end of the *enums* chapter.)

Comment: and to get values, you'd do the opposite:      let values = Object.keys(ApplicationMode); return values.slice(0, values.length / 2); Thank you for the idea.

Comment: there's no "keys" entry before the slice hence you don't need `keys.lenght-1`

Answer (score 8):

After further research and review of the other answers I now can formulate an answer to my question. I think its not possible to just use *ngFor to iterate over an enum without some code support in the component. The code support can consist of constructor code that turns the Enum into some sort of array or we can create a custom pipe that does something similar.

Answer (score 6):

```
export enum Priority {
  LL = 1,   // VERY LOW
  L = 2,    // LOW
  N = 3,    // NORMAL
  U = 4,    // HIGH
  UU = 5    // VERY HIGH
}
```

Your angular component.ts :

```
import { Priority } from './../shared/core/config/datas.config';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-yourcomponent',
  template: `
    <ng-container *ngFor="let p of getPriority">
       <div> {{p.key}} / {{p.value}} </div>
    </ng-container> 
  `
})

export class YourComponent {
  getPriority = this.getENUM(Priority);

  getENUM(ENUM:any): string[] {
    let myEnum = [];
    let objectEnum = Object.keys(ENUM);
    const values = objectEnum.slice( 0 , objectEnum.length / 2 );
    const keys = objectEnum.slice( objectEnum.length / 2 );

    for (let i = 0 ; i < objectEnum.length/2 ; i++ ) {
      myEnum.push( { key: keys[i], value: values[i] } ); 
    }
    return myEnum;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

using pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'enum'
})
export class EnumSelectPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any): [number, string][] {
    return Object.keys(value).filter(t => isNaN(+t)).map(t => [value[t], t]);
  }
}
```

and in the template:

```
<mat-select formControlName="type" placeholder="Package Type">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let pType of PackageTypes | enum" [value]="pType[0]">{{ pType[1] | title}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: this answer is better than the one accepted!

Answer (score 4):

**ES6** supports

```
export enum E {
    a = 'First',
    b = 'Second',
    c = 'Third'
}

let keyValueArray = Object.keys(E).map(k => ({key: k, value: E[k as any]}));
```

Answer (score 3):

I have the enum:

```
export enum FileCategory {
  passport = 'Multipass',
  agreement = 'Personal agreement',
  contract = 'Contract',
  photo = 'Self photos',
  other = 'Other'
}
```

In the component ts file:

```
export class MyBestComponent implements OnInit {
  fileCategory = FileCategory;

  // returns keys of enum
  fileKeys(): Array<string> {
    const keys = Object.keys(this.fileCategory);
    return keys;
  }

  // returns values of enum
  fileVals(): Array<string> {
    const keys = Object.keys(this.fileCategory);
    return keys.map(el => Object(this.fileCategory)[el]);
  }
```

In the HTML template display these enum's values and keys:

```
  <a *ngFor="let cat of fileVals()"
     (click)="addFileCategory(cat)">{{cat}}</a>
  <a *ngFor="let cat of fileKeys()"
     (click)="addFileCategory(cat)">{{cat}}</a>
```

Comment: the usage of the methods inside the ngFor will cause a big bunch of change detections as function return value changes are not detectable very well. You should put the "fileVals()" return value into a variable and read it from there.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use a generic Pipe, it will be more flexible and less redundant in your code. 
The problem with some previous propositions is that the typescript allow you to have different kind of enum, not only number/string.

For example:

```
export enum NotificationGrouping {
    GroupByCreatedAt = "GroupByCreatedAt", 
    GroupByCreatedByUser = "GroupByCreatedByUser", 
    GroupByEntity = "GroupByEntity", 
    GroupByAction = "GroupByAction", 
}
```

Here is my solution:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'enumToArray'
})
export class EnumToArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value, args: string[]): any {
    let result = [];
    var keys = Object.keys(value);
    var values = Object.values(value);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      result.push({ key: keys[i], value: values[i] });
    }
    return result; 
    //or if you want to order the result: 
    //return result.sort((a, b) => a.value < b.value ? -1 : 1);
  }
}
```

and the html will be:

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="groupKey">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let group of notificationGrouping | enumToArray"
              [value]="group.key">
    {{ group.value }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

in ts:

```
public notificationGrouping : NotificationGrouping
```

Note: Still interesting to see people putting a minus without explanation ... For others who could be interested by this solution, I can confirm that it works correctly.

Comment: where notificationGrouping  is defined?

Comment: although initially I expected a more simple solution already provided out of the box by typescript or angular (that wouldn't include any sorting by default), your solution is perfect, and I learned something new today: Pipes! :) Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 7, still getting a list of all keys and values when using keys().

Based on the above answers I am using this for a simple ENUM, seems cleaner and more OO:

```
export enum CategoryType {
    Type1,
    Type2,
    ...,
}

export namespace CategoryType {
    export function keys() {
        return Object.keys(CategoryType).filter(k => !isNaN(Number(k)));
    }
}
```

then in the template:

```
<option *ngFor="let type of types.keys()" [value]="type">{{types[type]}}</option>
```

The function becomes another entry in the enum, but gets filtered out like the other non-numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I am very late to it and my answer might not directly solve the question but it gets the job done. Today I came across a ask which revolved around the same problem, i.e., iterating `enum`.

I took to creating a `object` instead of using `enum`.

```
export const Roles= {
    0: "ServiceAdmin", 1: "CompanyAdmin", 2: "Foreman", 3: "AgentForeman", 
    4: "CrewMember", 5: "AgentCrewMember", 6: "Customer"
}
```

To iterate use like below:

```
let Number=Number; 
let roles= Roles; // in .ts file
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let role of roles | keyvalue" [value]="Number({{role.key}})">
        {{role.value}}
    </option>
</select>
```

To parse a value use like below:

```
let selectedRoleValue= 4; 
let Roles= Roles; // in .ts file

<div>{{Roles[selectedRoleValue]}}</div>
```

This will display

> CrewMember

Answer (score 0):

```
 fillKeysValueFromEnum<T>(type:T){
    return Object.keys(type).filter(t => isNaN(+t)).map(el => {
       return {
         key: el,
         value: Object(type)[el]
       }
     });
  }
```

Then

```
fillKeysValueFromEnum(ENUM_HERE)
```