# Use enum in angular to select drop menu item

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I want to implement select menu which uses enum data to display data and saved number based on the selected String:

HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group state_raw">
    <label for="state_raw">State</label>
    <select class="custom-select" name="state_raw" [(ngModel)]="merchant.state_raw" id="state_raw" required>
      <option selected></option>
      <option [value]="type" *ngFor="let type of types">{{type | formatType}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Enum which displaying data and translated number value:

```
export enum MerchantStatusType {
  'Being set up' = 1,
  'Live for processing' = 2,
  'Trading suspended' = 3,
  'Account suspended' = 4
}
```

Object for the elect menu:

```
export class MerchantNew {
  constructor(
    public name: string,
    public address_state: string,
  ) {}
}
```

How can this be implemented? I want to display String but save number into database?

EDIT: I tried this:

ENUM:

```
export enum MerchantStateType {
  being_set_up = 1,
  live_for_processing = 2,
  trading_suspended = 3,
  account_suspended = 4,
}

export const MerchantStateType2LabelMapping = {
  [MerchantStateType.being_set_up]: "Being set up",
  [MerchantStateType.live_for_processing]: "Live for processing",
  [MerchantStateType.trading_suspended]: "Trading suspended",
  [MerchantStateType.account_suspended]: "Account suspended",
}
```

Component:

```
public MerchantStateType2LabelMapping = MerchantStateType2LabelMapping;

public stateTypes = Object.values(MerchantStateType);
```

HTML code:

```
<select class="custom-select" name="state_raw" [(ngModel)]="merchant.state_raw" id="state_raw" required>
      <!--<option selected></option>-->
      <option [value]="stateType" *ngFor="let stateType of stateTypes">{{ MerchantStateType2LabelMapping[stateType] }}</option>
```

But I get 4 empty rows and 4 lines of the states.

[image]

Comment: I do not know which part blocks you. It seems that you have it almost done. Please look at the sample in doc: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form#question-model. It might help you.

Comment: Can you show me how to use the enum into the html code?

Comment: @PeterPenzov: Can you show what are `merchant` and `types`?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38554562/how-can-i-use-ngfor-to-iterate-over-typescript-enum-as-an-array-of-strings

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I usually do it in 3 steps.

First, declare a separate enum and a mapping from the enum values to labels. This way both enum values and labels can be later changed just in one place without changing any other code.

```ts
// FileTypes.enum.ts

export enum FileTypesEnum {
    CSV = "CSV",
    JSON = "JSON",
    XML = "XML",
}

// optional: Record type annotation guaranties that 
// all the values from the enum are presented in the mapping
export const FileType2LabelMapping: Record<FileTypesEnum, string> = {
    [FileTypesEnum.CSV]: "Here's Csv",
    [FileTypesEnum.JSON]: "Here's Json",
    [FileTypesEnum.XML]: "Here's Xml",
};
```

Then import them into a component and stick them in a public property, so they will be available in the view:

```ts
// my.component.ts

import {FileTypesEnum, FileType2LabelMapping} from "../FileTypes.enum";

@Component({ ... })
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    public FileType2LabelMapping = FileType2LabelMapping;

    public fileTypes = Object.values(FileTypesEnum);

    constructor(){}
}
```

And then in the view i'm doing ngFor over enum's values and map them to labels:

```html
 <!-- my.component.html -->

 <select ...>
  <option *ngFor="let fileType of fileTypes"
          [value]="fileType">
    {{FileType2LabelMapping[fileType]}}
  </option>
</select>
```

## Update:

String-valued and numeric enums compile to different objects.

So it looks like you have to additionally filter your array

```
public stateTypes = Object.values(MerchantStateType).filter(value => typeof value === 'number');
```

Comment: Thanks but I have a several words for key "Being set up" and you have CSV. How I can use it?

Comment: @PeterPenzov You can put this stuff in the label mapping and use a simple one-word identifier for enum key for easy-to-use

Comment: I found a bug. I get 4 empty lines and 4 values into the drop down list. Are you sure that your code is working properly?

Comment: @PeterPenzov I don't understand  what whis means "But I get 4 empty rows and 4 lines of the states." Can you take a screenshot?

Comment: @PeterPenzov oh, I see. That's because I usually use string valued enums, not 1, 2, 3

You can see that they compile to the different shape. (My link is too long for a comment, so I'll add it to the answer, click Run and check the console). So you have to account for this shape when declaring  `public stateTypes =`

Comment: Can you update the post please in order to handle enum with number, please?

Comment: You must filter your array. Something like this
`public stateTypes = Object.values(MerchantStateType).filter(value => typeof value === 'number');`

Comment: @PeterPenzov looks like it's a pretty common solution 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51536142/2036886

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you know how I can display the first value by default?

Answer (score 20):

Another simple way for Making Enum into dropdown or selecct List,

1. Define Enum

```
export enum ConditionalOperator {
    Equals="Equals",
    NEquals="NEquals", 
    GT="GT", 
    GTE="GTE", 
    LT="LT", 
    }
```

2. In component assign enum to a variable and in the constructor take all enum keys to another defined array

```
    conditionalOperator = ConditionalOperator;
    enumKeys=[];
    
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
      this.enumKeys=Object.keys(this.conditionalOperator);
    }
```

3. And in the HTML file simply iterate through enum keys is an assign value as following,

```
    <select>
    <option value='' disabled selected>Operator</option>
    <option *ngFor="let name of enumKeys" [value]="name"> {{conditionalOperator[name]}} </option>
    </select>
```

Comment: this didn't work for me.

First I had this error at `enumKeys=[]`: Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.

If I change the line to `enumKeys: string[] = []` then I get this error on server start:

 `conditionalOperator[name]` gives error: No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof ConditionalOperator'.

Comment: i had to add keyvalue pipe to the enum and use name.value to make it work

Answer (score 0):

if anyone using **NG-ZORRO** template.

Follow the above solution[[Click]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62697318/7921804), written by @mramsath

Then try this:

Update **constructor** or leave as it is. i updated for fetching *values*.

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
      this.enumKeys=Object.values(this.conditionalOperator);
    }
```

Here is the main part:

```
<nz-select name="yourFormPostName" #yourFormPostName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="data.yourFormPostName" nzPlaceHolder="Select Type" nzAllowClear style="width: 95%;">
<nz-option nzDisabled nzLabel="Select" nzValue="disabled"></nz-option>
<nz-option *ngFor="let name of enumKeys" [nzValue]="name" [nzLabel]="name"> </nz-option>
</nz-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In component ts :

```
function createEnum(values) {
      return {
        get: key => values[key],
        getAll: () => values
      };
    }
    
    const FileTypesEnum = createEnum({
        CSV = "CSV",
        JSON = "JSON",
        XML = "XML",
    });
```

in component html:

```
 <select ...>
  <option *ngFor="let fileType of fileTypes"
          [value]="fileType">
    {{FileTypesEnum.get(fileType)}}
  </option>
</select>
```