# How to iterate object keys using *ngFor

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to iterate [object object] using *ngFor in Angular 2. 
The problem is the object is not array of object but object of object which contains further objects.

```
{

  "data": {
    "id": 834,
    "first_name": "GS",
    "last_name": "Shahid",
    "phone": "03215110224",
    "role": null,
    "email": "test@example.com",
    "picture": **{ <-- I want to get thumb: url but not able to fetch that**
      "url": null,
      "thumb": {
        "url": null
      }
    },
    "address": "Nishtar Colony",
    "city_id": 2,
    "provider": "email",
    "uid": "test@example.com"
  }
}
```

I know we can use pipe to iterate the object but how we can iterate further from object to object means **data->picture->thum:url**.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046138/how-to-use-ngfor-with-object/37046743#37046743

Comment: You're perhaps lookin for recursive functions.

Comment: I don't see any difficulty here, if you have array of objects, you can itterate with ngFor easily

Comment: @Umar : Could you please put two of them so we could have a bigger picture ?

Comment: @Milad that is not array of object, that is the main problem. that is whole packed object, which contain further object like data->picture->thumb->url . i want to access the thumb0->url

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/35534959/5043867

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74827855/6666348

Answer (score 208, accepted):

**Angular 6.0.0**

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#610-2018-07-25

introduced a `KeyValuePipe`

See also https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

> ```ts
> @Component({
>   selector: 'keyvalue-pipe',
>   template: `<span>
>     <p>Object</p>
>     <div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue">
>       {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
>     </div>
>     <p>Map</p>
>     <div *ngFor="let item of map | keyvalue">
>       {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
>     </div>
>   </span>`
> })
> export class KeyValuePipeComponent {
>   object: {[key: number]: string} = {2: 'foo', 1: 'bar'};
>   map = new Map([[2, 'foo'], [1, 'bar']]);
> }
> ```

**original**

You can use a pipe

```ts
@Pipe({ name: 'keys',  pure: false })
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args: any[] = null): any {
        return Object.keys(value)//.map(key => value[key]);
    }
}
```

```ts
<div *ngFor="let key of objs | keys">
```

See also [How to iterate object keys using *ngFor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046138/how-to-use-ngfor-with-object/37046743#37046743)

Comment: thanks for reply! by this approach now i can access the picture->url but not picture->thumb->url. how to further iterate into it ..

 <div *ngFor="let key of posts |  objs">
    <ion-avatar item-left  *ngIf="key=='picture'">
        <img  [src]="posts[key].url"> <-- picture url here want thumb url which is futher into picture object
    </ion-avatar>
       
         </div>

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what the comment is about. Why can't you access picture->thumb->url? Perhaps `[src]="posts[key].thumb.url"`?

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear you could make it work.

Comment: i have an other json response, i am using the same approach as above but getting error,  Cannot convert undefined or null to object.

here is a json response.

{
  "id": 1,
  "food": "McDonalds Sharebox Chicken Plus (Drink - Coke)",
  "user_id": 834,
  "rating_id": null,
  "runner_id": 43,
}

Comment: Made a small change `Object.keys(value||{})` to make it support async values as well. `Cannot convert undefined or null to object` probably happened when the value was not yet resolved. I wonder if this can be coupled with `async` pipe?

Comment: is the pipe removed in a later version? I can't seem to find it in common.

Comment: @PraveenPuglia The `keyvalue` pipe was added in 6.0.0 beta. You probably need a newer Angular version or add the pipe from my original answer to your project.

Comment: I am actually on angular version 6.0.7 but I still don't get it.

Comment: It was added 6.1.0

Comment: How to add the keyValyePipe. It doesn't exist by default.

Comment: If you imported `CommonModule` it should be available.

Comment: Nice elegant solution, work for Angular older versions (< 6).

Answer (score 59):

I think the most elegant way to do that is to use the javascript [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) like this (I had first implemented a pipe for that but for me, it just complicated my work unnecessary):

in the Component pass Object to template:

```
Object = Object;
```

then in the template:

```
<div *ngFor="let key of Object.keys(objs)">
   my key: {{key}}
   my object {{objs[key] | json}} <!-- hier I could use ngFor again with Object.keys(objs[key]) -->
</div>
```

If you have a lot of subobjects you should create a component that will print the object for you. By printing the values and keys as you want and on an subobject calling itselfe  recursively.

[Hier](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6sxa2x) you can find an stackblitz demo for both methods.

Comment: Not sure if this is the ideal way! But it works. Seems like an optimal solution for my requirement.

Comment: This is perfect! I've been looking for this for the past 30 minutes! Works exactly as expected on an object like this: [nosings: {a : 1, b: 2}, communal_carpets: {a:1, b:2, c:3}]

Answer (score 17):

I know this question is already answered but I have one solution for this same.

You can also use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) inside of `*ngFor` to get required result.

I have created a demo on **[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-iterate-object-keys-using-ngfor?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**. I hope this will help/guide to you/others.

**CODE SNIPPET**

> HTML Code

```
<div *ngFor="let key of Object.keys(myObj)">
  <p>Key-> {{key}} and value is -> {{myObj[key]}}</p>
</div>
```

> .ts file code

```
Object = Object;

myObj = {
    "id": 834,
    "first_name": "GS",
    "last_name": "Shahid",
    "phone": "1234567890",
    "role": null,
    "email": "test@example.com",
    "picture": {
        "url": null,
        "thumb": {
            "url": null
        }
    },
    "address": "XYZ Colony",
    "city_id": 2,
    "provider": "email",
    "uid": "test@example.com"
}
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iterator-stringobj can you please look at this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55589669/cannot-find-a-differ-supporting-object-of-type-string-in-angular6

Answer (score 12):

You have to create custom pipe.

```
import { Injectable, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
   name: 'keyobject'
})
@Injectable()
export class Keyobject {

transform(value, args:string[]):any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
        keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
    return keys;
}}
```

And then use it in your *ngFor

```
*ngFor="let item of data | keyobject"
```

Comment: i have done with that, the problem is ngFor use with array of object, in my case that is not array of object, object into object then further object into object like this data->picture->thumb->url .

Answer (score 12):

Looping through object in Angular HTML templates

keyValuePipe is introduced in Angular: Please refer https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

Quick code:

```js
<p>Object</p>
    <div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue">
      {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
    </div>
    <p>Map</p>
    <div *ngFor="let item of map | keyvalue">
      {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

> 1.Create a custom pipe to get keys.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'keys'
})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return Object.keys(value);
  }
}
```

> 2. In angular template file, you can use *ngFor and iterate over your object object

```
<div class ="test" *ngFor="let key of Obj | keys">
    {{key}}
    {{Obj[key].property}
<div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular now has a type of iterate Object for exactly this scenario, called a Set. It fit my needs when I found this question searching. You create the set, "add" to it like you'd "push" to an array, and drop it in an ngFor just like an array. No pipes or anything.

```
this.myObjList = new Set();
```

...

```
this.myObjList.add(obj);
```

...

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let object of myObjList">
     {{object}}
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What type do you use for `myObjList`?
When I tried it, my linter says: `Type 'Set<any>' is not assignable to type 'IMyInterface'`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on Set.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `map()` operator on your response,you could maybe chain a `toArray()` operator to it...then you  should be able to iterate through newly created array...at least that worked for me :)

Comment: object does not use toArray

Answer (score 0):

After doing a lot of troubleshooting nested loops in the template, I found that this worked better for my use:

(For one thing I was trying to iterate agm-polygon and it wouldn't let me nest divs).

In component.ts:

```
Object = Object

values= Object.values(this.arrayOfObjects)
```

In component.html:

```
<div *ngFor='let value of values'>{{value.property}}</div>
```

Once you retrieve the values, you do have an Iterable, and do not need to worry about also iterating through the keys in the template, which can get complex and look messy.

Answer (score -9):

i would do this:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of data" (click)='onclick(item)'>{{item.picture.url}}</li>
```