# Counter of rows in a table

Tags: javascript, html, angular, counter

How can I add a simple counter to my table. I d like to store this number in a variable (if it is possible using just HTML)

**HTML**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="carTable" class="table table-bordred table-striped">
        <thead>
            <th>Car ID</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let car of cars">
                 <td>{{system.systemID}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443963/angular2-ngfor-how-to-count-the-number-of-looping-values

Comment: Here's the [complete list](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables) of variables you can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple actually :

```
<tr *ngFor="let car of cars; let i = index">
  <td>{{system.systemID}}</td>
</tr>
```

Now `i` is your counter !

Answer (score 0):

You can add a index number with for loop like

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="carTable" class="table table-bordred table-striped">
        <thead>
            <th>Car ID</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let car of cars;let i = index">
                 <td>{{i +1}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

here your variable is stored as i and it starts with zero index.