# Angular2 Error Cannot read property

Tags: angular

i have a method function that create object. here my function

```
packetdata:any[];

ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getonepacket(this.nopacket).subscribe(
      data => {
          return this.packetdata = data;
      },
      error => console.log(this.errorMessage = <any>error)
    )
  }
```

if i use console log this.packet it result object like this

```
Object {idpacket: 3, packetname: "Packet C", packetdesc: "SMS 20 sms/hari, Storage 20Gb", packetprize: "Rp. 300.000/bulan", packettime: 30}
```

i try to put that each value on my table like this

```
<h3 class="page-header">Your Bill Information</h3>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let item of packetdata"> Packet Name </th>
    <td>{{item.packetname}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let item of packetdata"> Description </th>
    <td> {{item.packetdesc}} </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let item of packetdata"> Prize </th>
    <td> {{item.packetprize}} </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let item of packetdata"> Minimal Contract time (day) </th>
    <td> {{item.packettime}} </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but it return error Error Cannot read property.
How to resolve this?.

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Comment: like that sir @GünterZöchbauer
Error: Error in ./BillComponent class BillComponent - inline template:5:8 caused by: Cannot read property 'packetname' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<th *ngFor="let item of packetdata"> Packet Name </th>
<td>{{item.packetname}}</td>
```

can't work

`item` is only available within `<th>` (the element that has the `*ngFor` directive applied)
     Packet Name {{item.packetname}}

You might want

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of packetdata">
  <th> Packet Name </th>
  <td>{{item.packetname}}</td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: i change my code using yours sit. but it came up with error again

Comment: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396435/how-to-iterate-object-object-using-ngfor-in-angular-2/41396558#41396558

Answer (score 1):

try to replace the ngFor to `<td>` like this :

```
<tr>
    <th > Packet Name </th>
    <td *ngFor="let item of packetdata">{{item.packetname}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add *ngIf="packetdata" to tag table and remove return inside de subscribe.