# how to avoid multiple executions of a impure pipe in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi I am using Angular 2 pipe to return the keys of object, it is an impure pipe and It is being executed multiple times which is blocking some other script, how can I avoid multiple executions of the impure pipes? my code is as follows :

```
 import {Pipe,PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
    @Pipe({ name: 'NgforObjPipe', pure: true })
    export class NgforObjPipe implements PipeTransform {
        transform(value, args:string[]):any {
        let keys = [];
        for (let key in value) {
            keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
        }
        console.log('pipeeeeeeeeeeeeeee', keys);
        return keys;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In what sense is this pipe impure? Since you are specifying `pure: true`, why do you think this is a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to prevent that. That's what an impure pipe is for.

What you can do is, to ensure that as little work is done inside the the `transform()` method as possible, for example by caching results and only recalculate when the passed value has actually changed.

You can also use `Object.keys()` to get more efficient code.
See also [How to iterate [object object] using *ngFor in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396435/how-to-iterate-object-object-using-ngfor-in-angular-2/41396558#41396558)

`ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` can be used to reduce the number of times change detection is run, to minimize the number of calls to the pipe.

Comment: Can't `OnPush` strategy helps in this case?

Comment: Was about to add that to my answer. Yes, I think it can help.

Comment: Thanks mate, but doing manual transformation of object inside component make more sense +1

Comment: Inside the component it's easier to know when a value was changed (for example depending by an event), and therefore it's easier to reduce the number of times the code is executed to the required minimum. So yes. I agree with your conclusion.

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer, your answer helped me in fixing it..:)

Comment: Hi Günter, could you please explain how to cache results in the Pipes for future checks? Are you suggesting keeping in global varibales.

Comment: No need for a global variable, just a field inside the pipe.

Answer (score 2):

There could be two ways of  doing this.

1. You could consider passing this Object value as `Input` to component and make your component `ChangeDetectionStrategy` onPush.
2. Apply your `NgforObjPipe` Pipe over `collection` from component itself by calling its transform method manually like `NgforObjPipe.tranform()`.

Comment: Thanks @Pankaj Parkar, your answer helped me in fixing it..:)