# Angular NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am getting an error while trying to loop through and display data using ngFor.

Actual error in console "Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

Here is my code:

> //TS Component

```
var lssessionsObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('sessionsObject'));
```

> //localstorage array

```
lssessionObject = {"total_rows":1,"offset":0,"rows":[{"id":"245fd1cbf38f79256a7443a0b5001461","key":"245fd1cbf38f79256a7443a0b5001461","value":{"cinemaid":"0001","session":"168970","filmid":"HO00003858","screen":"VIP 1","datetime":"2017-07-22T11:00:00","attributes":["3D Film","Scene VIP"]}}]}
```

> HTML

```
<ion-slides class="image-slider" slidesPerView="3" pager="true">
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let item of sessionsObject" class="border">
        <button ion-item color="primary" id={{item.filmid}} class="bottom-slider">
            {{item.filmid}}
        </button>

    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Please assist me

Comment: As the message clearly states: You need to pass an array to your ngFor not an object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396435/how-to-iterate-object-object-using-ngfor-in-angular-2/41396558#41396558

Comment: @echonax, you need to pass an iterable, it can be anything with the iterable interface, see my answer below

Comment: hey, so did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45321622/2545680) help?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, timezone issues, I tried your suggestion but had no luck. I am not sure if it is an Ionic 3 problem.

Comment: I then proceeded to looping through the object and converting to an array, but I'm quite stuck on this.

Comment: @eohdev, so did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

`ngFor` works with iterables. An iterable object is the object that implements `[Symbol.iterator]` method that returns an iterator. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators). Only Array and Map are iterable in JS by default.

Objects in JavaScript are not iterable. And your `sessionsObject` is simple object and it therefore doesn't implement `[Symbol.iterator]` method. But you can easily implement it yourself:

```
// 
lssessionsObject[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
   for (p in this) yield this[p];
}
```