# Bind array value in HTML

Tags: angular, typescript

The output of my data in console.log:

```
{TotalPendingResponseCount: 0, TotalRequestSendCount: 1, TotalRequestReceivedCount: 1, TotalRequestRejectCount: 3}
```

To capture these information I am holding it in array:

```
userData : arrayResponseCount[];
To get the result:
this.dataservice.getData(Url).
    subscribe((res: any) => 
    { this.userData = res });
  }
```

And my arrayResponseCount class is:

```
class arrayResponseCount {
  constructor(public TotalRequestSendCount: string, public TotalPendingResponseCount: string,
              public TotalRequestRejectCount: string, public TotalRequestReceivedCount: string
  ){}
}
```

Now I need to bind the value in HTML. For this I am using the syntex is

{{userData.TotalRequestSendCount}}

But it thrown the exception i.e. **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'TotalRequestSendCount' of undefined**.

Do you have any idea for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Angular first evaluates your binding `{{userData.TotalRequestSendCount}}`, `userData` doesn't have a value yet.

Use instead

```
{{userData?.TotalRequestSendCount}}
```

to tell Angular it shouldn't try accessing `TotalRequestSendCount` while `userData` is null (it's called safe-navigation operator)

Comment: Now after implementing this I got the below error:  ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Comment: Your value is an object, not an array. `*ngFor` doesn't support binding to objects directly. This answer shows a pipe that converts the value so that you can use it with `*ngFor` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396435/how-to-iterate-object-object-using-ngfor-in-angular-2/41396558#41396558

Comment: Perfect.. Thanks .. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are getting data from an async request, there could be a delay, you can handle with the safe navigation operator **`?`**,

```
{{userData?.TotalRequestSendCount}}
```

Comment: Now after implementing this I got the below error:  ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'