# Angular 4. ngFor and async issue

Tags: angular

I tried to use async pipe and ngFor directive in Angular 4.4.
It works fine but I got weird error message in console:

"Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

```
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let event of events | async">
  </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>


export class EventsComponent {

  events: Observable<Array<Event>>;

  constructor(private eventService: EventService) {
      this.events = this.eventService.findAll();
  }
}
```

Please advise

Comment: `*ngFor` only iterates arrays, but doesn't support iterating objects. You can use a pipe like shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396435/how-to-iterate-object-object-using-ngfor-in-angular-2/41396558#41396558

Comment: The events actually emitted by the observable returned by findAll() seem to be objects, not arrays. Check  what you really return from that method (at runtime).

Comment: Well, findAll method returns Observable of array. So ngFor actually displays returned data. The only issue is error message in the console.

Comment: Here's signature of findAll function:   findAll(): Observable<Array<Event>> {
    return this.http.get<Array<Event>>(this._baseUrl);
  }

Comment: The signature is irrelevant. TypeScript only checks types at compile time. It has no way to ensure that your backend service actually returns JSON representing an array of events. So it trusts you on that. You need to check what it actually returns **at runtime**.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your error in a Plunker :

https://plnkr.co/edit/KpEnf2KOm8XJXurBTjFQ?p=preview

To create the error, I made my service method return an object instead of the expected array :

```
findAll(): Observable<Array<string>> {
  return Observable.of({ data: ['Francis', 'Emilie', 'Diego'] });
}
```

Then, I called the method from the component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let name of names | async">{{ name }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {

  names: string;

  constructor(private eventService: EventService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.findAll();
  }

  findAll(): void {
    this.names = this.eventService.findAll();
  }
}
```

And I got

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type
>   'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

As already said **JB Nizet** in a comment below your post, you should check what you really return from the *findAll* method.

Comment: Thank you, Arpp. It turned out that I had two *ngFor on page(for desktop and mobile version). Second *ngFor missed async pipe so it was hidden but still raised an error.