# How to make nested *ngFor with firebaselist?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic3, angularfire2

I would like to render nested `*ngFor` with data coming from Firebase using angularFire2.

So my data are structured like this :[image]

and I want to use the first level of `subjects` list in a first `*ngFor` and the child level in a nested `*ngFor`.

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let mainSubject of subjects | async">
        {{mainSubject.name}}
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item *ngFor="let childSubject of mainSubject.subjects | async">
                {{childSubject.name}}
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I think I have to use the map operator from rxjs to transform the list to what I need.

Something like this :

```
this.db.list(`${this.mainSubjectsPath}`).map((value) => {
    console.log(value);
    // make some transformation...
});
```

but the map function is never called.

Any idea of how I can do that?

Thanks!

Comment: What happened when you do like above?

Comment: i get the following error : Runtime Error
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because you are trying to iterate over an Object (subjects), which is not supported in angular templates. *ngFor can only be applied to an array.

There are several possible solutions to this issue:

- change your data structure, so you iterate over the elements of an array.
- write a custom pipe, to iterate through an object. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41396558).