# Loop over object Ionic3/Angular4

Tags: json, angular

I´m trying to loop over a content. I tried some answers found here in StackOverflow but none works for me.

I have this JSON

```
{  
   "-KmdNgomUUnfV8fkzne_":{  
      "name":"Abastecimento"
   },
   "-KmdNgzguGKbCEfyQ3F0":{  
      "name":"Consórcios"
   },
   "-KmdNh9_jtBlFqY1Y_Rj":{  
      "name":"Consultoria aeronáutica"
   },
   "-KmdNhKNCVEiJ2Ou8bUV":{  
      "name":"Cursos e treinamentos"
   },
   "-KmdNhVRoKfaCM--304M":{  
      "name":"Financiamento"
   },
   "-KmdNhfIC6fA0kDJcVBq":{  
      "name":"Hangaragem"
   },
   "-KmdNhu0X-PteQMyHp_n":{  
      "name":"Mecânica"
   },
   "-KmdNi6ZmmYXnoOTXoC5":{  
      "name":"Táxi Aéreo"
   },
   "-KmdNiHFhiX_crXB1L2R":{  
      "name":"Outros"
   }
}
```

I´m trying to loop using this code

```
<button ion-item *ngFor="let cat of subcategories" (click)="onSubcategorySelect(cat)">
              {{ cat.name }} 
</button>
```

It's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396435/how-to-iterate-object-object-using-ngfor-in-angular-2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular's `ng-for` requires any element with `Iterable` interface to work and it's not the case for a plain Object. You need to "convert" this object in an array, the easier way is with `forEach` or a `for/in` loop:

Anywhere in your code you'll iterate through your object and save it in a new variable to be used in `ngFor`:

```
public newSubcategories: any[] = []; // DECLARE A NEW EMPTY ARRAY IN THE TOP OF YOUR CLASS

this.subcategories.forEach(item => {
  this.newSubcategories.push(a);
});
```

If you need to mantain the key use `for/in` to push a new object with the key.

```
public newSubcategories: any[] = []; // DECLARE A NEW EMPTY ARRAY IN THE TOP OF YOUR CLASS

for(let key in this.subcategories){
  this.newSubcategories.push({
    key: key,
    name: this.subcategories[key].name
  });
}
```

Finally your HTML

```
<button ion-item *ngFor="let cat of newSubcategories" (click)="onSubcategorySelect(cat)">
  {{ cat.name }} 
</button>
```

With this you'll be able to use `ng-for` in your new array.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this was helpful, just to add on isn't `this.newSubcategories.push(a);` supposed to be `this.newSubcategories.push(item);`