# How to use for loop in ionic 3 for not iterating objects

Tags: json, typescript, ionic3

Hi I know this may looks funny.But just wanted to know can we use this object for iteration in for loop.

https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=53f2c082ae1e48aca6e0e2cd7d60e106
please refer the link for the json data.

All the objects of patient_lifestyle has same design input and label.I  don't want to create that many input and label inside form so i created a component including label and ion input naming app-input
now i am accessing in pages like

```
<app-input *ngFor="let item of patient_lifestyle" [model]="item"></app-input>
```

As patient_lifestyle is not an array I am not able to use this.

Comment: Similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773429/loop-over-object-ionic3-angular4

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Did u solve your issue?