# Angular5 HttpClient returning undefined in component view

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm trying to access an API that returns a JSON with some data that I then need to present in my component html by using `ngFor` because it's an object. Inside the `http.get` function if I `console.log` the returned data, it appears fine. But when I try to present it in my view, it's not working.

Here is my component.ts:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export class AnonimoComponent implements OnInit {
    public medicamentos: Object;

    private baseURL = 'http://website.com/api/medicamentos';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {  }

    ngOnInit() {
         this.getMedicamentos();
    }

    getMedicamentos(){
        interface MedicamentoResponse {
            id: number;
            Name: string;
            Preco: number;
        }

        this.http.get<MedicamentoResponse>(this.baseURL).subscribe((data) => {
             this.medicamentos = data;
             console.log("First:\n" + this.medicamentos);
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my html:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let med of medicamentos$ | async">
        {{med}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, it's not presenting anything. Any ideas?

Comment: @Igor I believe you are right. I've changed it to `*ngFor`, but it's still not working :/

Comment: Why aren't you using something like a BehaviorSubject?

Comment: `medicamentos` != `medicamentos$` and it is not `async` because you returned the actual result in the subscribe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `|async` pipe, you can't use `.subscribe()`.

It should be

```
getMedicamentos(){
    this.medicamentos = this.http.get<MedicamentoResponse>(this.baseURL);
}
```

If you use

```
 this.medicamentos = data;
```

then you don't need `|async`

Comment: What I'm getting from the api is: `id:4,name:"Amoxapina",preco:12`, and now the console is giving this error: `Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'Amoxapina'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396435/how-to-iterate-object-object-using-ngfor-in-angular-2/41396558#41396558

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
*ngFor="let med of medicamentos$ | async"
```

to

```
*ngFor="let med of medicamentos"
```

- You can't use `async` because `medicamentos` is not an Observable, you assigned the result directly in the `subscribe` in your component's code
- Casing and variable name are critical, you can't add a character like `$` at the end of the variable name in the template and have it still work.

Finally you should validate that what is being assigned to `medicamentos` is actually an array, verify the response in your browser's debugger.

Answer (score 0):

*ngFor is not work with JSON..

You have to Convert it to Array.

**Try This**

```
this.medicamentos = data.json();
```