# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. solution?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have API call which like this

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngfor-simple-nbh4sn)

**Component:**

```
this._newTripApi.getData().subscribe(selected => {
          this.selectedSettings = selected;
          this.isLoading = false;
        })
```

**Service:**

```
public getData(): Observable<any> 
{
      return this._api.get(`instances/${this._config.getData().user.instance._id}?fields=newTripSettings`)
            .map(res => res.data.newTripSettings);
}
```

When i use res.json() it says json is not a function, JSON response is shown below, i need to show all newtripSettings object in compopnent html but it says:
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. solution?

```
{
  "data": {
    "_id": "5aaab927c756c86c15d3b1dc",
    "newTripSettings": {
      "betweenSites": {
        "enabled": true,
        "consultation": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "radiotherapy": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "chemotherapy": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "dialysis": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "coronarography": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "scan": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "transfer": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "urgentPatientStop": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "urgentOther": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "otherPaidByHospital": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "otherPaidByPatient": {
          "enabled": true
      },
      "fromSite": {
        "enabled": true
        "discharge": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "consultation": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "radiotherapy": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "chemotherapy": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "dialysis": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "coronarography": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "scan": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "urgentPatientStop": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "urgentOther": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "otherPaidByHospital": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "otherPaidByPatient": {
          "enabled": true
        }
      },
      "toSite": {
        "enabled": true,
        "hospitalisation": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "consultation": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "radiotherapy": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "chemotherapy": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "dialysis": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "coronarography": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "scan": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "otherPaidByHospital": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "otherPaidByPatient": {
          "enabled": true
        }
      },
      "other": {
        "enabled": true,
        "discharge": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "hospitalisation": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "consultation": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "radiotherapy": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "chemotherapy": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "dialysis": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "coronarography": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "scan": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "otherPaidByPatient": {
          "enabled": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: when i did in console ({}).toString() it says: "[object Object]"

Comment: Aha, looking at your stackblitz: you cannot ngFor with an object. But you can do const `keys = Object.keys(this.notifications)` which returns an array and and iterate over that. Or  even `this.notifications = Array.from(Object.keys(data), k=>data[k]);` You might need something more thorough so you don't lose your object-keys. Like `k=> { data[k].id = k; return data[k}; }`

Comment: @user2385919 it clearly say's that there is an object and ngFor not working on an object so you need to convert your object in an array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41396558/1497533 This was a pretty clean solution. But fixing the source is the best option if possible. Maybe add another api endpoint.

Comment: @ippi your solution works thanks and thanks others too, comment 1 i already tried