# How to get value from object in html file in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I have array like this

```
this.location={"asdsad":{"asdsad":"qweqwe"}};

<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in location">
{{value | json}} 
</li>
```

Tried to print in html like above but it's not working.

Comment: ng-repeat does not exist in angular 6. Ty to use *ngFor. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396435/how-to-iterate-object-keys-using-ngfor/41396558

Comment: I don't see any array here. The value of `this.location` is an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Angular 6.1.0, you can use the keyvalue pipe:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of location | keyvalue">
    <p>{{ item.value | json }}</p>
</div>
```

Not originally my answer, found it here: [access key and value of object using *ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Object.keys` in the template and use it in `*ngFor` instead of `ng-repeat`.

```
 objectKeys = Object.keys;
 location = {'asdsad': {'asdsad': 'qweqwe'}};


 <li *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(location)">
  {{key + ' : ' + location[key]}}
</li>
```

Comment: looks like its working but not properly.. I have json object iike this
`{
      "name": "john",
      "properties": {
       "age": 25,
       "sex": "m"
      },
      "salary": 1000
     };`

I get in result
`john
[object Object]
1000~

why object object is there. second thing i need to know how I can know this is object or not

Comment: Because "properties" IS an object.

Answer (score 0):

This code is work for me. i'm not sure it's best way to solve your problem.

```
component:

    location = {asdsad :{asdsad:"qweqwe"}};
     objectKeys = Object.keys;

Html:


     <li *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(location)">
            {{key + ' ' + (location[key].asdsad | json)}}
     </li>
```