# How to get the value of object inside an array by using its key in angular2+

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

```
var arr=[
        {Key0: "myValue1"},
        {Key0: "myValue2"},
        {Key0: "myValue3"},
        {Key1: "myValue4"},
        {Key2: "myValue5"}, ]
```

from the above array, I want to get the values using its key in *ngFor angular,
for example, key0 values I want to display along with other values values,

I have also tried like this but can't able to get the desired output

```
                         <li mat-list-item *ngFor='let C of arr'>
                             {{C}}</li>
```

### Note:

I tried like `{{c.key0}}` but it prints only `key0` values, but here I want all the values like `key1,key2`

thanks in advance.

Comment: How many keys are you expecting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [access key and value of object using \*ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate object keys using \*ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396435/how-to-iterate-object-keys-using-ngfor)

Comment: I want to get almost all the values in array using its key @Arcteezy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should modify your array in typescript first by using iteration logic. And then show it using *ngFor.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in: [How to iterate object keys using *ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396435/how-to-iterate-object-keys-using-ngfor)

You can use (angular v6+):

```
<div *ngFor='let C of arr | keyvalue">
   {{C.key}}:{{C.value}}
</div>
```

Comment: I tried using {{c.value}}, but i'm getting [object:object] @Swoox

Comment: any other fix for {{c.value}} to get the values

Comment: @sivaIT You can use `{{c.value | json}}` to show the object, then select which exact field you want from it, or add a custom `toString()` method to it.

Comment: @sivaIT Ohh sorry I see your array is different. `<div *ngFor='let C of arr[0] | keyvalue">`
or you make `this.arr = { {Key0: "myValue1"} }`