# how to iterate array values inside json object in angular

Tags: angular

I have json result like this

```
{
   "modelList":["modelName1","modelName2"],
   "modelNamesList":["modelName1","modelName2"],
   "yearList":["2021","2020","2019","2018"]
}
```

I need only years list from above object so I am not getting how to do that, can anyone help me, thank you

I have done something like this

**home.component.ts**

```
 export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    catlogData: any ={
                "modelList":["modelName1","modelName2"],
                "modelNamesList":["modelName1","modelName2"],
                "yearList":["2021","2020","2019","2018"]
    };


    ngOnInit(): void {}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<ul *ngFor="let a of catlogData">
    <li>year:{{a.yearList[i]}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate object keys using \*ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396435/how-to-iterate-object-keys-using-ngfor)

Comment: You can apply ```*ngFor``` on ```catlogData.yearList```, you can access directly json property with ```.```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly  access the `yearsList` from `catlogData` since it's an Object(`catlogData.yearsList`). Incase if you want iterate whole `catlogData` object, Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396435/how-to-iterate-object-keys-using-ngfor)

Try like this

```
 <div>
   <ul *ngFor="let year of catlogData.yearList">
     <li>years: {{ year }}</li>
   </ul>
 </div
```

Comment: happy to help!!