# Custom pipe not correctly imported

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have to iterate over an object keys inside a template, so I made this custom pipe :

```js
import {PipeTransform, Pipe} from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({name: "keys"})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any[]): any[] {
    return Object.keys(value);
  }
}
```

And inside my page it's imported as follow :

```js
import {KeysPipe} from "../../pipes/keys-pipe";
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-history',
  templateUrl: 'history.html',
  pipes: [ KeysPipe ]
})
export class HistoryPage {}
```

But when i build project there is this error that occurs :

> Argument of type '{ selector: string; templateUrl: string; pipes: typeof KeysPipe[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'pipes' does not exist in type 'Component'.

Any idea ? I didn't declare it in `app.module.ts` nor `app.component.ts`.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `pipes` in `@Component()` anymore since quite some time.

Now it's

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ KeysPipe ]
```

See also [Select based on enum in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35750059/select-based-on-enum-in-angular2/35750252#35750252)

Comment: Aw, works nice. I must have read some old tutorials then ... Thanks alot :)