# How to use custom pipes in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

So I was following this post [access key and value of object using *ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor)

However I'm getting a 'pipe could not be found error'.

- I've done this `@Pipe({name: 'keys'})`
- I've exported the class.
- I've imported it in my app.module.ts
- I've put it in the declarations
- I've included it in my app.component.ts (where I'm using it)

What else am I missing?

Comment: Don't describe your code. Post it. Don't describe the error. Post it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom pipe not correctly imported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932265/custom-pipe-not-correctly-imported)

Comment: I want to close this but stackoverflow warns me not to close it :\

Answer (score 2):

Create pipe using below command:
**`ng g p double`**

if you are using angular2 cli then only you need to add filter like **`{{ mytext | double }}** in your template html.

There is no need to add file in your component but check the pipe should be included in app.module.ts **`@NgModule({declarations: [DoublePipe]})`** .

Answer (score 0):

Have you put it in your `AppModule`'s `providers` list?

Comment: It works now for some reason... should it be in `declarations` or `providers`? Because it's in declarations right now and it works. Maybe I just didn't let it update... there seems to be a caching issue with Angular 2, where it won't display updates unless you delete the cache.