# Binding enum into options in selector using ngFor

Tags: angular

I want to bind an enum as options in a HTML selector

```
    export enum MY_ENUM{
    ONE = 'One',
    TWO = 'Two',
    THREE = 'Three'
}
```

How do I bind this as options for my HTML select using ngFor

Comment: Duplicate [click this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35750059/select-based-on-enum-in-angular2) ........

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select based on enum in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35750059/select-based-on-enum-in-angular2)

Comment: Tried that but it didnt work for me

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Object.values` to get a list of the enum values like so:

```js
this.options = Object.value(MY_ENUM);
```

And then in the template

```html
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">{{option}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: As you can see the key and the value are different. So this doesnt work for me

Comment: Your question didn't state which value you wanted to display and which one you wanted to use for the value so i assumed you wanted to use the string value for both. You could do `this.options = Object.entries(MY_ENUM).map(([key, value]) => ({key, value}))` or something else depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let opt of opts"
  [value]="opt.id" >
  {{opt.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

where opts is an array that you build from Enum

```
enum EnumExample {
  OPT1 = "opt1",
  OPT2 = "opt2"
}

export class Example {
  public opts: any[];
  constructor(){
    this.opts = [
      {id: "OPT1", name=EnumExample.OPT1},
      {id: "OPT2", name=EnumExample.OPT2}];

  }
}
```

I didnt find a way to do directly from Enum.