# enum type gives double array in typescript

Tags: typescript, enums

I want to create a dropdown from enum data type but when I try to change enum into object with name and value; enum array return twice of the enum member. using a function from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111657/how-does-one-get-the-names-of-typescript-enum-entries/18112474#18112474)

- Typescript: **v 2.3.3**
- Angular **v 4.3.4**

ps. can not update typescript version dues to angular version. below is the relevant code

```
export enum FrequencyEnum {
    H1 = <any>'1 Hour',
    H12 = <any>'12 Hours',
    D1 = <any>'24 Hours',
    D7 = <any>'7 Days',
    M1 = <any>'1 Month',
    M3 = <any>'3 Months',
    CD = <any>'Custom Date Range'
};
export interface Frequency {
    name: string;
    value: string;
    range?: { from: string; to: string; };
}

export function enumSelector(definition) {
    console.log('definition: ', definition);
    return Object.keys(definition)
        .map(key => ({ value: definition[key], name: key }));
}

this.frequnecyList = enumSelector(FrequencyEnum);
```

it gives array of 14 objects

```
[
  {
    "value": "1 Hour",
    "name": "H1"
  },
  {
    "value": "H1",
    "name": "1 Hour"
  },
  {
    "value": "12 Hours",
    "name": "H12"
  },
  {
    "value": "H12",
    "name": "12 Hours"
  },
  {
    "value": "24 Hours",
    "name": "D1"
  },
  {
    "value": "D1",
    "name": "24 Hours"
  },
  {
    "value": "7 Days",
    "name": "D7"
  },
  {
    "value": "D7",
    "name": "7 Days"
  },
  {
    "value": "1 Month",
    "name": "M1"
  },
  {
    "value": "M1",
    "name": "1 Month"
  },
  {
    "value": "3 Months",
    "name": "M3"
  },
  {
    "value": "M3",
    "name": "3 Months"
  },
  {
    "value": "Custom Date Range",
    "name": "CD"
  },
  {
    "value": "CD",
    "name": "Custom Date Range"
  }
]
```

how can I get only 7 value ( equal to enum member) in the final array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not really possible due to the way TypeScript implements enums. If you look at the generated JavaScript code for your enum, you'll see:

```
var FrequencyEnum;
(function (FrequencyEnum) {
    FrequencyEnum[FrequencyEnum["H1"] = '1 Hour'] = "H1";
    FrequencyEnum[FrequencyEnum["H12"] = '12 Hours'] = "H12";
    FrequencyEnum[FrequencyEnum["D1"] = '24 Hours'] = "D1";
    FrequencyEnum[FrequencyEnum["D7"] = '7 Days'] = "D7";
    FrequencyEnum[FrequencyEnum["M1"] = '1 Month'] = "M1";
    FrequencyEnum[FrequencyEnum["M3"] = '3 Months'] = "M3";
    FrequencyEnum[FrequencyEnum["CD"] = 'Custom Date Range'] = "CD";
})(FrequencyEnum || (FrequencyEnum = {}));
;
```

An assignment expression in JavaScript returns its right value, meaning that `FrequencyEnum["H1"] = '1 Hour'` evaluates to `1 Hour` and effectively gives you a property `'1 Hour'` with value `"H1"` in the resulting object. That's why you see the the values also appearing as the keys and hence twice the size of key/values that you expect.

You can do a trick and filter out every even key in the list, but it's not a very solid solution:

```
export function enumSelector(definition: any) {
    return Object.keys(FrequencyEnum)
                 .filter((key, i) => i % 2 == 0)
                 .map(key => ({ value: definition[key], name: key }))
}
```

This will give you the output:

```
[ { value: '1 Hour', name: 'H1' },
  { value: '12 Hours', name: 'H12' },
  { value: '24 Hours', name: 'D1' },
  { value: '7 Days', name: 'D7' },
  { value: '1 Month', name: 'M1' },
  { value: '3 Months', name: 'M3' },
  { value: 'Custom Date Range', name: 'CD' } ]
```

Another (better) solution is to not use enums and simply use an object literal instead of an enum:

```
const FrequencyEnum = {
    H1: '1 Hour',
    H12: '12 Hours',
    D1: '24 Hours',
    D7: '7 Days',
    M1: '1 Month',
    M3: '3 Months',
    CD: 'Custom Date Range'
};
```

Comment: Yes  I did the same constant approach. thanks for the solution.

Comment: You mean using the object literal instead of the enum? Also please accept the answer if you're happy with it :-)

Comment: yes object literal instead of enum. there was one more way to use npm package [enum-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-string-enums)  but that was lengthy way