# How to get my original variable name on a function in type script

Tags: typescript, enums

```
export enum Animals {
        Cow,
        Pig
    }
```

I have a function receiving an Enum:

```
export function printEnumName(Enum: any) {
 console.log(someFancyFunctiontoPrintMyEnumName(Enum)); //It should print the enum's name "Animals"
}
```

I want to implement that fancy function to avoid sending it by parameter.

**EDIT:**
I don't want to print the variables from Animals, like I mentioned on the commented line (also on the post's title) on the console log I want to print "Animals" the enum's name not the enum's variables on the function that is receiving Animals as a parameter.
I tried to print using this approach but It didin't work:

```
    export function printEnumName(Enum: any) {
        for (let element in this.printEnumName) {
            console.log(element); //It would be nice to print "Animals" literally animals 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They have good description for enums https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html.

Just access enum key.

```
Animals.Cow
```

To get names, try

```
  Object.keys(Animals).filter((v) => {
      return isNaN(parseInt(v));
   });
```

Comment: But seems it is duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111657/how-does-one-get-the-names-of-typescript-enum-entries

Comment: It's not duplicate since I don't want to print the variables names inside the enum...

Answer (score 0):

It's helpful to look at what the enum becomes after transpiling to JavaScript:

```
var Animals;
(function (Animals) {
    Animals[Animals["Cow"] = 0] = "Cow";
    Animals[Animals["Pig"] = 1] = "Pig";
})(Animals || (Animals = {}));
```

`Animals` becomes a regular variable. To get its name, you can apply any method you'd apply to get a variable name in JavaScript, for example `Object.keys({Animals})[0]`.

For more discussion on the subject: [Variable name as a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602141/variable-name-as-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: I do not want to print the variables inside animals, I want to print Animals on the function printEnumName @lanterlog

Comment: The code I posted is not code to print anything, it just illustrates that Animals is a regular variable. I have now added an example solution that will print `"Animals"` to clarify.