# How to access an enum value in an Angular 5 view

Tags: angular

I am currently referencing the `enum` int value directly in my `html` view, but I would prefer to reference by the enum name - for example, as I do in TypeScript code

```
 if (this.nodeType === NodeType.HostService) {
      ...
 }
```

I have an enum defined as:

```js
export enum NodeType {
    Location,
    Host,
    HostAccessPoint,
    HostStorage,
    HostService
}
```

and in my html view, I'm loading specific components (which include reactive forms) within a modal as follows - and it all depends up on the `enum` value:

```html
<div class="modal-body">
      <config-edit-storage-node *ngIf="selectedNode && selectedNodeTypeEnum===3" 
                        [node]="selectedNode" [nodeType]="selectedNodeTypeEnum" 
                        (cancelEdit)="cancelEdit()" (saveEdit)="onSaveEdit($event)">
        </config-edit-storage-node>
        
        <config-edit-service-node *ngIf="selectedNode && selectedNodeTypeEnum===4"
                        [node]="selectedNode" [nodeType]="selectedNodeTypeEnum" 
                        (cancelEdit)="cancelEdit()" (saveEdit)="onSaveEdit($event)">
        </config-edit-service-node>
        
</div>
```

In my component I'm setting **that.selectedNodeTypeEnum** :

```js
export class ConfigNetworkTreeComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedNode: INode;
  selectedNodeTypeEnum: NodeType = null;
  selectedNodeTypeStr: string;
  
  setNodeEvents() {
   let selectedObj = that.getSelectedNode(nodeID);        
   that.selectedNode = selectedObj['selectedNode'];      
   that.selectedNodeTypeStr = selectedObj['nodeType'];
   that.selectedNodeTypeEnum = NodeType[that.selectedNodeTypeStr];
  
  }
  ...
}
```

Bottom line is that I would rather use this style of coding in the html:

```
*ngIf="selectedNode && selectedNodeTypeEnum===NodeType.HostService"
```

as opposed to referencing the enum int vaue itself.

Can it be done ?

thanks and regards.

Comment: `NodeType[NodeType.HostService]` see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111657/how-does-one-get-the-names-of-typescript-enum-entries

Answer (score 28):

Since the [expression context](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-context) of the template is the component instance, you should assign the `NodeType` enum to a property of the component class to make it available in the template:

```
export class ConfigNetworkTreeComponent {
  public NodeTypeEnum = NodeType;  // Note: use the = operator
  ...
}
```

You can then use that property in the template to refer to `NodeType` values:

```
*ngIf="selectedNode && selectedNodeType === NodeTypeEnum.HostService"
```

See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r6f9bq) for a demo.

Comment: No, I can't get that to work. I need to debug further. I also tried the other poster's suggestion `NodeType[NodeType.HostService]`

Comment: It's such a habit to use : I think everyone is overlooking the =. TY

Comment: I also have not been able to use an exported enum for conditional checks in the view. It works for sure if defined in the view directly. But @bob.mazzo has exported the enum.

Comment: @SQueek - Exporting the enum is not enough. You have to assign it to a property of the component class to make it available in the template, because the [expression context](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-context) of the template is the component instance.

Comment: @connorsfan I did it like you explained before, but for me it has not worked. Can you please adjust your Stackblitz so that the enum is exported and is not defined within the component class? Would be cool if it works.

Comment: @SQueek - I had not declared the enum in the component class. It was in the same file but outside of the component class. I modified [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r6f9bq?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) to show how it works when the enum is declared in a separate file.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for helping and providing immediate support. I would flag your answer as the correct one.

Comment: This works well, but just a note that this will only work if the export enum is NOT defined as a const.

Comment: Awesome! I have a `BaseComponent` class that I have put it in, and now it works in all my components.

Answer (score 9):

**Simplest way to use enum in HTML with intellisense**

Your enum

```
export enum NodeType {
    Location,
    Host
}
```

Your component class

```
export class YourComponent {

    get Node() {
       return NodeType
    }

}
```

Your component's HTML

```
<div>{{Node.Location}}</div> // 0
<span *ngIf="Node.Location == 0">Location</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a method for returning string representation of enum element in your component, like:

```
getActionName(): string {
    return Action[this.action];
  }
```

And in html template call it like:

```
 <button type="submit" [disabled]="!userProfileForm.valid" class="btn btn-danger">
            {{getActionName()}}</button>
```

When your declared enum is like:

```
    export enum Action {
  update, create
}
```