# Trying to use enum in a template file, which doesnt belong to the component

Tags: angular, angularjs-scope

If i want to leverage enums which exist outside the scope of my component.

```
export enum Template { Foo = 0, Bar = 1, Fuzz = 2 }
```

but when trying to leverage it my template file, it will throw an error.

```
<div *ngIf="model.type == Template.Foo"></div>
```

for example.  When serving the application, it does not understand what Template is.  If I create a property in my component, Template, as follows it will work:

```
Template = Template
```

essentially creating the enum inside the scope of the component as its own property.  I just dont like it though, it feels dirty and not right.

I thought there was a property in the Component decorator to essentially add exports for the template, but that does not seem to be the case.

Is the way I am doing it correct, or is there a way which doesnt feel like a hack?

Thank you.

*Edit* The reason I asked this, is that the AngularDart way of doing it is through an `exports` property in the Component Annotation.  See: https://webdev.dartlang.org/api/angular/angular/Component/exports and was not sure if this is just a divergence of technology or if there was an option that does similar without property assignment.

Comment: I think that assigning the enum to a property of the component class is correct. As I mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50357404/1009922), the [expresson context](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-context) of the template code is the component instance.

Comment: Agreed. If you think about the component as the "template resolution context", then everything that the template binds to should be encapsulated in that template. So if there is a need to bind to an external enum or service, define a property for it in the component to use for binding.

Comment: I added an edit which explains my reasoning.  I was doing angular dart for the better part of 2 years, and they leveraged a property in the Component annotation, so you can see why I was confused.