# Can Angular's template for loop loop through an enum?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm reviewing this [bit of code that is the model for a select filter component](https://stackblitz.com/edit/akita-todos-app?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftodos%2Ffilter%2Ffilters.component.ts) for `Todo`s:

```
    export enum VISIBILITY_FILTER {
      SHOW_COMPLETED = 'SHOW_COMPLETED',
      SHOW_ACTIVE = 'SHOW_ACTIVE',
      SHOW_ALL = 'SHOW_ALL'
    }

    export type TodoFilter = {
      label: string;
      value: VISIBILITY_FILTER;
    };

    export const initialFilters: TodoFilter[] = [
      { label: 'All', value: VISIBILITY_FILTER.SHOW_ALL },
      { label: 'Completed', value: VISIBILITY_FILTER.SHOW_COMPLETED },
      { label: 'Active', value: VISIBILITY_FILTER.SHOW_ACTIVE }
    ];
```

It looks as if all of that could be replaced with:

```
export enum VISIBILITY_FILTER {
  SHOW_COMPLETED = 'Completed',
  SHOW_ACTIVE = 'Active',
  SHOW_ALL = 'All'
}
```

So the `active` filter property would just be typed by the enum `VISIBILITY_FILTER` and we would loop through then enum in the template like this (Pseudo code):

```
    <option *ngFor="let filter of VISIBILITY_FILTER;" [ngValue]="filter">{{VISIBILITY_FILTER[VISIBILITY_FILTER.filter]}}
    </option>
```

Does that seem reasonable or did I miss something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one get the names of TypeScript enum entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111657/how-does-one-get-the-names-of-typescript-enum-entries)

Comment: I'm certain its not a duplicate, the OP wants to iterate the enum in angular, not get the names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try:

```
public get visFilterValues() {
  return Object.keys(VISIBILITY_FILTER).map(k => VISIBILITY_FILTER[k]);
}
```

and

```
<option *ngFor="let filter of visFilterValues" [ngValue]="filter">{{filter}}</option>
```