# TypeScript - force interface to use a string enum member

Tags: typescript

I have an autogenerated enum (from NSwag) which generates me the following:

```
export enum Frequency {
  Weekly = 1, 
  Fortnightly = 2, 
}
```

For my interface I want to say that it's a string value that must have come from the `Frequency`. The closest I got was:

```
interface GtmProduct {
  dimension6: keyof Frequency;
}
```

I also tried  `dimension6: 'weekly' | 'fortnightly'` to no avail.

In usage it looks like this:

```
{ ...
  dimension6: Frequency[frequency].toLowerCase() //frequency here will be `Frequency.Weekly`
}
```

This errors with: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"toString" | "toFixed" | "toExponential" | "toPrecision" | "valueOf" | "toLocaleString"'.`

Is there any way to achieve what I want using TS 2.9 or should I simply type it as a string?

Comment: "For my interface I want to say that it's a string value that must have come from the Frequency"  
What do you mean by this?

Comment: you may need to process the enum in a similar fashion in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111657/how-does-one-get-the-names-of-typescript-enum-entries

Comment: @aframestor what I meant by this was I want the only acceptable values for `dimension6` to be either `Weekly` or `Fortnightly`. If `Frequency` was to get another value (i.e. `Monthly`) then I would want that to "just work" without further code changes to this area.

Comment: I see what you mean now. However I don't think you can achieve what you want without using a custom type for dimension6.  If you want it to be a string you'll have to implement these constraints logically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - you have to use `keyof typeof Frequency` in order to get union type of '"Weekly" | "Fortnightly"'. Follow this [TS issue 14294](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14294) for more details.

[image]
Also you can use type casting when you set `GtmProduct` values. So here is the final solution:

```
type KeyOfFrequencey = keyof typeof Frequency;

interface GtmProduct {
  dimension6: KeyOfFrequencey;
}

const toKeyOf = (f: Frequency): KeyOfFrequencey => Frequency[f] as KeyOfFrequencey;

const frequency = Frequency.Weekly
const a: GtmProduct = {
  dimension6: toKeyOf(frequency)
}
```

But in your example I see `.toLowerCase()` which is probably not correct, since your Enum keys have uppercased properties and you're going to lowercase them in your interface. This is why I removed lowercase in my example.

If you want to use lowercased values, than you have to use lowercased keys in your enum as well:

```
enum Frequency {
  weekly = 1, 
  fortnightly = 2, 
}
```

Try this example in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-hewmmu?file=index.ts)

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over how the `Frequency` enum is generated (it's autogenerated by a tool as a much smaller part of the overall system) so changing how those are generated is unfortunately out of the question. Thanks for the above though, that is a really good starting point.

Comment: U r welcome. But why you need `toLowerCase()` the Enum props ?

Comment: Our existing enhanced ecomm tracking has been set up with lower case frequency so I was hoping to get parity in our new area. Whether or not GTM cares about case is a separate question I'll need to check I guess.

Comment: Got it. So this case you can lower case the properties inside `toKeyOf` method: `Frequency[f].toLocaleLowerCase() as KeyOfFrequencey`. I don't see any problems here.

Comment: Heh, you were one step ahead of me. Just got it working with that as well. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

You want to get i.e. 'weekly' in the dimension6 variable? 
Have a look to https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html it is a Reverse Mapping you want.