# How to display enum value in ag-grid cell field value?

Tags: typescript, enums, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2, ag-grid-angular

I am using ag-grid latest version (^20). I have tried the cell rendering but not sure how to display the string instead of enums.

**In sample.component.html code**

```
<ag-grid-angular 
    #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 350px;" 
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [showToolPanel]="showToolPanel"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    [rowData]="rowData">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

**In sample.component.ts code**

```
 export const PROJECT_LIST_COLUMNS = [
        { headerName: 'Code', field: 'code', width: 120 },
        { headerName: 'Name', field: 'name', width: 200 },
        { headerName: 'Customer', field: 'customerName', width: 200 },
        { headerName: 'Manager', field: 'manager', width: 150 },
        { headerName: 'Project Group', field: 'projectGroup', width: 150 },

        {
            headerName: 'End Date',
            field: 'endDate',
            width: 130,
        },
        {
            headerName: 'Status', //what I want is from the below project status file I want the string 
            field: 'status', 
            width: 150,
            cellRenderer: data => {
                return data.value ? data.value : 'not found';
            },
        },
    ];
```

And this is **my project-status.ts file**

```
export enum ProjectStatus {
    Queue = -3,
    Hold= -2,
    Proposal = -1,
    NS= 0,
    WIP= 1,
    Completed = 2,
    Posted= 3,
    Closed = 4,
}
```

Not sure how to achieve this. Kindly help

Comment: You wanted to change `headerName` based on `cellValue`?

Comment: Sorry. I have amended my question to make more meaningful. I am looking for cell value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ProjectStatus[data.value]` to get the text of the enum value.

```
    {
        headerName: 'Status',
        field: 'status', 
        width: 150,
        cellRenderer: data => {
            return (data.value !== null && data.value !== undefined)
                    ? ProjectStatus[data.value] : 'not found';
        },
    }
```

Note: Make sure to update your condition as `(data.value !== null && data.value !== undefined)`, otherwise `ProjectStatus.NS` will show you `not found`.

**Reference:** *[How does one get the names of TypeScript enum entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42172322/1417185)*

**Detailed reference:**: *[TypeScript Handbook - Enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)*

> **Reverse mappings**
>
> In addition to creating an object with property names
>   for members, numeric enums members also get a reverse mapping from
>   enum values to enum names. For example, in this example:
>
> ```
> enum Enum { A }  
> let a = Enum.A;
> let nameOfA = Enum[a]; // "A"
> ```

Comment: Thank you  so much Paritosh and thanks for the typescript links too. It works.