# Iterate over enum as named constants (not values!)

Tags: typescript, enums

I've found [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111657/how-to-get-names-of-enum-entries) [posts](https://riptutorial.com/typescript/example/17503/how-to-get-all-enum-values) about how to get an array of possible *values* for TypeScript enums, but I want an array of the typed named constants.

And it is very possible this TypeScript newbie is using the wrong terms/words and that this is part of the problem...

```
enum Color {
    RED = "red",
    GREEN = "green"
}

// Object.keys(Color) gives me ["RED", "GREEN"] as strings but I want:
const allColors = new Array<Color>(Color.RED, Color.GREEN);

function takesColor(color: Color) {
    console.log("Color is", color);
}

// So I can iterate over all colors and call takesColor() like so:
for (let color of allColors) {
    takesColor(color);
}
```

How do I create `allColors` without explicity listing every member? My `allColors` above isn't DRY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
// These two are the same type
const allColors : Color[] = new Array<Color>(Color.RED, Color.GREEN);
const allColors2: Color[] = Object.values(Color);
```

If you put a break in you'll see that allColors and allColors2 are the same array (["red", "green"]), and you haven't had to list all the members to create allColors2.

Comment: Ahhh. I now see that your `allColors2` variable has the compile-time Typescript type `Color[]` and not as I thought: `string[]`. I've taken the liberty of updating your code example to make that even clearer...

Comment: That's fine.  The point @Erik Philips is making (whilst forgetting to answer the question!) is that Color[] IS string[] in the underlying JavaScript, and the TypeScript compiler is trying to pretend we have proper enum support by putting a layer on top of that.  If you've come from a language which has native enums you'll find the TypeScript enums are a bit tricky as a result.

Comment: Color[] is string[] *at runtime* not at compile time.