# filter data based on enum values - Typescript

Tags: typescript, enums

I have an enum with two keys. I would like to filter my data based on the keys of the enum and return an object.

```
enum ArchiveStatus {
  Current = 0,
  Archive = 1,
}

const data = [{name:'A', Archive_Status: 0}, {name: 'B', Archive_Status: 0}, {name: 'C', Archive_Status: 1}, {name: 'D', Archive_Status: 1}];

const filteredData = {
    Current: data.filter(item => item.Archive_Status === ArchiveStatus.Current),
    Archive: data.filter(item => item.Archive_Status === ArchiveStatus.Archive)
}

console.log(filteredData)
```

Expectyed Result:

```
{ "Current": [ { "name": "A", "Archive_Status": 0 }, { "name": "B", "Archive_Status": 0 } ], "Archive": [ { "name": "C", "Archive_Status": 1 }, { "name": "D", "Archive_Status": 1 } ] }
```

I am able to achieve it this way. But I want to dynamically create new properties from the enum and filter the data based on the Archive_Status and add it to this object. For example, if the enum has 10 properties, I do not want to type in the key names every time into the object. Please advice.

Comment: Yes, you can do this. The enum is a runtime object. Try `console.log(ArchiveStatus)` to see what it looks like. You can work with it like any other object (e.g. using `Object.entires` and the like).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Get the enum names

If you want to dynamically create all keys in an object according to an enum, you need to [get the enum keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111657/how-to-get-names-of-enum-entries). There is no built in way to do that - the problem is that TypeScript generates a double binding between keys and values to ensure the uniqueness of both.

```
enum ArchiveStatus {
  Current = 0,
  Archive = 1,
}
```

effectively compiles to:

```js
ArchiveStatus = {
  "Current": 0,
  "Archive": 1,
  0: "Current",
  1: "Archive",
}
```

However, if the enum values are all numbers, you can filter them out with `Object.values(ArchiveStatus).filter(x => typeof x !== "number")` which will leave you with the names only:

```
enum ArchiveStatus {
  Current = 0,
  Archive =  1
}

//create a type for the names for type safety later
type ArchiveStatusName = keyof typeof ArchiveStatus;

const enumNames = Object.values(ArchiveStatus)
    .filter(x => typeof x !== "number") as ArchiveStatusName[]; //type assertion needed as compiler cannot determine this is safe
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAggTgYwBYEsBuwDKAXAhtsAZygG8AoKKAYTDjlGygF4oAGAGgtkVQ2coCMZAL5kyAenEJ6+YFFxRsATwAOcgGYB7OIqRyQuCMGJadytVEK51wZVAA2suGXNz4ydFjwFCAOUNyLADWwEqa6oqqwOHcHhg4+EQA3GIImiCEjKCQ-kbELADyAEYAVsAI2AB0aLj2YMYAFO68XomEAJRclJXqKPbYwHANAB7MAHyRajGjAIRMLABE4BBFgwvt8sTNngk+ucAA2gC6SVCSrpuEg9go6VAgwMAAJs+bUGkQKn2D77ggIJpGC8BnAICgHroUMQoZZrMBUulCJp7MBKvZNABzBrZCD7DpJIA)

JavaScript demonstration:

```js
const ArchiveStatus = {
  "Current": 0,
  "Archive": 1,
  0: "Current",
  1: "Archive",
}

const enumNames = Object.values(ArchiveStatus)
  .filter(x => typeof x !== "number");

console.log(enumNames);
```

## Generalise the filtering

Now the filter calls can be generalised to call them with any of the names of the enum. That is what we want to be doing because we already have the names.

This is easily doable using a curried function. Here is your code refactored to use it:

```
//formalised the interface for the data
interface DataItem {
    name: string;
    Archive_Status: ArchiveStatus;
}

//generalised filter function for each status
const statusFilter = (status: ArchiveStatus) => (item: DataItem) : boolean => 
    item.Archive_Status === status;

//using the filters
const filteredData = {
    Current: data.filter(statusFilter(ArchiveStatus.Current)),
    Archive: data.filter(statusFilter(ArchiveStatus.Archive))
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAggTgYwBYEsBuwDKAXAhtsAZygG8AoKKAYTDjlGygF4oAGAGgtkVQ2agCMZAL5kyAenEAzAPZwIuADYpCwACZRsSYFBQhswOFNwIdsuJu1Q1+XGT0GjJnQBFbASQPRylSiFwQwABcUITYcHoA5gDcXJTwyOjAAPo4+EQhCbxYeASEsaIS4pGghkoq6lBSKIqOVWAgCNgoMiBVclDAJkihuURkCK1hvemEAGI1dSwAFGGjmTxJaXkAlMwAfFDTKF4hbniewBBrIQBGMjKKXW1Mm3G6XgB0WUmpfcRMnyN5sWKDIMMbHg9h4vABtAC6-DBJH8gSCAHIYAj2NxEhg3vM2MJUbCAsEoAiAEIotHZTF5EKsHGkOEEhFUUkvDHLDKCGl4+GElxMxYs94hATCCG-SREKKWMyTQyEAZDRjVWqGdT7XD8Hy+Gh0BghIG4R6Kxyzd4TJVwabMnKjR5a+j6FYrTi+MlJXW2A3S81zPKmo2W1mEZ584AOkR-IaXYCPRQySLTQ3KtSqlbRIA)

## Generate an object with the statuses and filtered data

With the tools above it's a matter of putting it all together. We can iterate over all of the `enumNames` and create an object with

- each name as a key
- the data filtered with that status as the value

JavaScript provides a convenience method for creating objects called [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) - it takes an array of pairs. For TypeScript it's an array of tuples of the type `[key: string, value: any]`. We can create such a structure and then give it to `Object.fromEntries` to generate the objects for us:

```
//create key-value pairs for the dynamically created object
const pairs = enumNames.map(name => [
    name, 
    data.filter(statusFilter(ArchiveStatus[name]))
]);

const filteredData = Object.fromEntries(pairs);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=29&pc=27#code/KYOwrgtgBAggTgYwBYEsBuwDKAXAhtsAZygG8AoKKAYTDjlGygF4oAGAGgtkVQ2agCMZAL5ky2AJ4AHYN2ToseAoQByuCLJYBrYBID2AMyiSZhub0X4iAbjEoQ2YHAO4EsgCL5cASUfRylJQg6sAAXFCE2HD2AOa2geYKAPo4VoTh8PIYqcq2omQIeiCREUpEAGIoADaOcPwAFJFpGTwKOUQAlMwAfFD1KH7hnni+wBBd4QBGenpVwLggPVBclANjAHSZFillxEz7pWm2BUUlACZeQ16jEADaALr8tyTBGqEA5DDv7IkYO81sYQ-F4hcLvABC31+wH+ynCrCBpFeYSg7yoUK2yXa6UEiJBb1R7gxrT+2PCAmE92OhWKjFAkDUGhxmOyu0ZwAe-AA8pMAFbABDYdY6CSEeosyzKDpcdYGaq1eoADyWKFUuBU9RUkEmTiVHX1UFwxAl2PZD2OAHoLQh6PhZCKALRoXBVMCyKS4FBwYgGPR1bBIWRnCSvFAIF1VCRQG3zRxnKB6PkC7AnWlQD1evZQekQdmEdYQXBSerIpa3FZQZE-CsXPCy+W6prKSo1XUm3a3ZH3fVkbvU06MOWt+hnYa4blJwWyuB6CAAUQc0WAYoz3o6-eKs2A6yqehi9SHtWAo6866AA)

## Filter out keys without any data

If needed, we can skip any keys where the value has no data. We can just remove pairs where the second item is an empty array:

```
//create key-value pairs for the dynamically created object
const pairs = enumNames.map(name => [
    name, 
    data.filter(statusFilter(ArchiveStatus[name]))
])
  .filter(([, value]) => value.length > 0); // remove any pair where the value is an empty array

const filteredData = Object.fromEntries(pairs);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/KYOwrgtgBAggTgYwBYEsBuwDKAXAhtsAZygG8AoKKAYTDjlGygF4oAGAGgtkVQ2agCMZAL5ky2AJ4AHYN2ToseAoQByuCLJYBrYBID2AMyiSZhub0X4iAbjEoQ2YHAO4EsgCL5cASUfRylJQg6sAAXFCE2HD2AOa2geYKAPo4VoTh8PIYqcq2omQIeiCREUpEAGIoADaOcPwAFJFpGTwKOUQAlMwAfFD1KH7hnni+wBBd4QBGenpVwLggPVBclANjAHSZFillxEz7pWm2BUUlACZeQ16jEADaALr8tyTBGqEA5DDv7IkYO81sYQ-F4hcLvABC31+wH+ynCrGE92OhWKjFAkDUGnS0PaqhCD34AHlJgArYAIbDrHQSQj1LZtXYdLjrAzVWr1AAeSxQeJU9RUkEmTk5HVFUFwxHp2V2mOAD2OAHoFQh6PhZNSALRoXBVMCyKS4FBwYgGPR1bBIWRnCSvFAIHVVCRQFXzRxnKB6Unk7AnVFQA1GvZQdEQWWEdYQXBSeqvTS9W4rKCxn6Ji54Fls4VNZSVGrCqWWZS3WP3UVkUvM1l5uD1eq3H7a3XAUtLRt69ZzEAxC1QXqsDrWKBKqD0CB6PgLJ0BuoAd0t9GMlqgbdkPPFizGUkk4rouAkYhRJSrtWAZ2GuCJXopLLgeggAFEHNFgLTp4QBwfTrNgB29DF6seTinueA5AA)

Comment: Just a small question: For this data, [{name:'A', Archive_Status: 0}, {name: 'B', Archive_Status: 0}], there is no Archive_Status with value of 1. So the end result should only contain Current, and Archive should not be present at all. In the solution you provided, the response contains Archive as an empty array. Can we fix it?

Comment: @a2441918 yes it's possible. We can filter out any pairs we don't need. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks. If the filtered array is empty, we do not need that key at all. Thanks