# is it possible to create dynamic properties to a class?

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

I am wrapping an enum in a class so I can map its values in TypeScript

```js
enum Color {
    RED = 0,
    GREEN = 1,
    BLUE = 2
}

const MapColor = new EnumMap(Color); // Wrapper

console.log(MapColor.map()) // [{ "key": "RED", "value": 0}, { "key": "GREEN","value": 1}, { "key": "BLUE",  "value": 2}] 
console.log(MapColor.entries()) // [["RED", 0], ["GREEN", 1], ["BLUE", 2]] 
console.log(MapColor.keys()) // ["RED", "GREEN", "BLUE"] 
console.log(MapColor.values()) //  [0, 1, 2]
```

Wrapper Class

```js
class EnumMap {
  private _map = new Map<string, string | number>();
  public enum: any;

  constructor(enumeration: any) {
    this.init(enumeration);
    return this;
  }

  private init(enumeration: any) {
    this._map = new Map<string, string | number>();

    for (let key in enumeration) {
      if (!isNaN(Number(key))) continue;
      const val = enumeration[key] as string | number;
      if (val !== undefined && val !== null) this._map.set(key, val);
    }

    this.enum = enumeration;
  }

  map = (): Object => Array.from(this._map.entries()).map((m) => ({ key: m[0], value: m[1] }));
  entries = (): any[] => Array.from(this._map.entries());
  keys = (): any[] => Array.from(this._map.keys());
  values = (): any[] => Array.from(this._map.values());
}
```

I would like to access an enum value directly, I want to do this

```
MapColor.RED  // 0
MapColor.RED.toString()  // 'RED'
```

Is it possible to create dynamic properties to a class? If possible, how would it be done?

Comment: Perfectly possible, using generics but why would you want to?

Comment: I want to do this `MapColor.RED  // 0` `MapColor.RED.toString()  // 'RED'`

Comment: Yes, that can be done, but using a class for it is pointless. A factory function that returns a wrapper object is much easier to write and the types are less complex.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get names of enum entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111657/how-to-get-names-of-enum-entries)

Comment: Hold on a second, forget about class stuff for a minute.  You want `MapColor.RED` to be the *primitive* numeric value `0`, and you want `MapColor.RED.toString()` to output the string `"RED"`?  Like, you want `MapColor.RED === Color.RED` to be `true` but `String(MapColor.RED)` to be `"RED"`, right?  Impossible.

Comment: I'm going to completely ignore the impossible edit to the question because otherwise the answer is just "no" and I've already started writing up the answer to the possible version of this 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASIDE:

I am ignoring the request that `MapColor.RED` be `0` but `MapColor.RED.toString()` evaluate to `"RED"`.  If you want `MapColor.RED === Color.RED` to be `true`, so that `MapColor.RED` is the  `number` (primitive data type) whose value is `0`, it is completely impossible for you to get `"RED"` as its string value, since  `(0).toString()` is just `"0"`.  If you want `MapColor.RED` to be a [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) (wrapper object), you could do it as `Object.assign(Number(0), {toString(){return "RED"})`, but what comes out of that is *awful*.  It kind of acts like `0` (`MapColor.RED + 5 === 5`), except when it doesn't, since `MapColor.RED === 0` is `false`, and `someObject[MapColor.RED]` will access the `RED` property of `someObject`, not the `0` property.  So you either cannot do this, or you can but you shouldn't.  So I'm pretending it doesn't exist.

---

ANSWER:

You can *implement* such a class by copying the properties of `enumeration` directly to `this` inside the constructor (or the `init()` method, I guess).  And you can *describe* the type of such a class constuctor using [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) via intersection.  What you cannot do is have the compiler verify that the implementation obeys the description.  You will therefore need to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) in several places to tell the compiler that your class instances and class constructor conform to the behavior in question:

```
class _EnumMap<T extends Record<keyof T, string | number>> {
    private _map = new Map<keyof T, T[keyof T]>();
    public enum!: T;

    constructor(enumeration: T) {
        this.init(enumeration);
        return this;
    }

    private init(enumeration: T) {
        this._map = new Map<keyof T, T[keyof T]>();

        for (let key in enumeration) {
            if (!isNaN(Number(key))) continue;
            const val = enumeration[key];
            if (val !== undefined && val !== null) {
                this._map.set(key, val);
                (this as any)[key] = val; // set value here
            }
        }

        this.enum = enumeration;
    }

    map = () => Array.from(this._map.entries())
        .map((m) => ({ key: m[0], value: m[1] })) as
        Array<{ [K in keyof T]: { key: K, value: T[K] } }[keyof T]>;
    entries = () => Array.from(this._map.entries()) as
        Array<{ [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]] }[keyof T]>;
    keys = () => Array.from(this._map.keys()) as Array<keyof T>;
    values = () => Array.from(this._map.values()) as Array<T[keyof T]>;
}
```

I have renamed `EnumMap` out of the way to `_EnumMap` and I restore the `EnumMap` name at the end:

```
type EnumMap<T extends Record<keyof T, string | number>> = _EnumMap<T> & T;
const EnumMap = _EnumMap as 
  new <T extends Record<keyof T, string | number>>(enumeration: T) => EnumMap<T>;
```

The renamed `EnumMap` is generic in the type `T` of the `enumeration` object passed to it.  Inside `init()` I write `this[key] = val`, but the compiler does not know that `this` should have keys corresponding to `key`, so I assert `this as any` to loosen up the compiler warnings.  I changed the output types of all your existing methods too, to correspond more correctly to what you're getting out of them... but you didn't ask for that, so keep `any` and `Object` (or probably `object`) if you must.

By writing `type EnumMap<T> = _EnumMap<T> & T`, I'm saying that an `EnumMap<T>` acts both as your original class, *and* as a `T`.  So if `T` looks sort of like `{RED: 0, GREEN: 1, BLUE: 2}`, then `EnumMap<T>` will also have those properties.  And by writing `const EnumMap = _EnumMap as new<T>(enumeration: T) => EnumMap<T>`, I'm saying that the original class constructor has been copied to a value named `EnumMap`, and can be treated as a class constructor for instances of the new `EnumMap<T>`.

---

Let's test it:

```
enum Color {
    RED = 0,
    GREEN = 1,
    BLUE = 2
}

const MapColor = new EnumMap(Color); // Wrapper

console.log(MapColor.map()) // [{ "key": "RED", "value": 0}, 
  // { "key": "GREEN","value": 1}, { "key": "BLUE",  "value": 2}] 
console.log(MapColor.entries()) // [["RED", 0], ["GREEN", 1], ["BLUE", 2]] 
console.log(MapColor.keys()) // ["RED", "GREEN", "BLUE"] 
console.log(MapColor.values()) //  [0, 1, 2] 
console.log(MapColor.RED) // 0
console.log(MapColor.GREEN) // 1
console.log(MapColor.BLUE) // 2
```

Looks good to me.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAED6CiA7ArgWwLJgA4B4Aq0ApgB4AuhiAJjAEqHAD2ATpTgNaECeDAZtHgBpoEUkwCWiAObQAPtBSoARoSYA+VdADeAKGh7oWcQDcw5OKmzQAvPMIB3aJlwdufQfwDaL3vwC6qgAoASgBuXX0sZEUQMWAiBQBCAC5+MPC9RkQRJmRgUmYAijQVUzEGRBS8IK10-T1SAAsxCAA6CTFSQoUS0jLEUNq6pkJSZCZEaEbmsLqAX21awzETM3bOotQevsrqnTq6qdbYCyxrWwcndi4fdzwva7d-YLT9-R5maACQEegXaAl4sUmKVyrtBq9-nwAglmgA5MCwgKwtDKJgBFxBTHQTK9FCEGYQuqZETQEwgM4bLble6cXwEwl6MRQsnQBJWGzIKiEHgSQiUaAAMgFpLA5LZNhQIBAYIZEMOLWO2BaEBG6K4QjJA1lrwCh2gkH1iE4QRpvjOZPpDPmhPm4PqTVaGwp3WBvXKlttdROZ2C1g0AEEmMDOC0eEwGKhdQ6FScWhRRGJCBBgkEWicAgFUNUrBoAppflwUqgPAAGXwa0XIQhFjwARjNsyxkDt0EDwZw+Y8AGl-hNvI8UvmXCkuxWQFXKt2G9BZjSbv5LfHxEmfdmA0GwCGwxGo80Y0ql4nk02IC225uO9Bu72C64-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)