# Calling C# enum to React Component

Tags: c#, .net, reactjs, api, enums

I am using enum in my .Net Core Web API to list types of cuisine in my project such as

```
public enum CuisineClass
{
    American = 1,
    British = 2,
    Chinese = 3
}
```

and so on.

At this point when I'm mapping my GetRestaurantDto and calling my endpoint from in my react SPA, I get the int instead of the string.

Is there a way to get the string instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JsonStringEnumConverter. In .NET 5 use it this way:

```
`services.AddControllers()
.AddJsonOptions(o =>
 {
o.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
});`
```

Comment: Perfect! I can't believe that's all that was needed. Tried so many different things. It's working just like I wanted to. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Why return the full name? If you are using typescript you can setup [the enum on your reactjs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) application too and handle it as such.

```
export enum CuisineClass
{
    American = 1,
    British = 2,
    Chinese = 3
}
```

You can then access the strings from TS if you want [How to get names of enum entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111657/how-to-get-names-of-enum-entries)

Comment: I'm not using Typescript unfortunately. The solution above is all I needed. Thanks for your reply though!