# How to get name of enum generic type in typescript(angular)?

Tags: typescript

I have an enum on angular like

```
export enum Status{
    Pending = 1,
    Working = 2,
    Finish = 3
}
```

using

```
var name = GetName<Status>(Status);
```

and I have other method to get name of enum

```
export function GetName<T>(en: T): string{
    // I want to get name here to result 'Status'
}
```

Comment: It's about Typescript not an Angular.

Comment: No I need name of enum to get result is 'Status' in string.

Comment: @MuhammetCanTONBUL yes in typescript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get names of enum entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18111657/1260204)

Comment: @Igor that not what I want.

Comment: Variable containing object is generated for enum. So you're asking to get the name of variable which not possible (and probably won't be useful anyway because will be changed after minification) https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwMowIY2QZwG8AoOMuABSQBMBLRAczgF44BGAGlPIHVoBrek1YAmLuTgAxerXwALFnADMxAL5A

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge you can't do this with Enumerators, however, if you created a typed map object, you could assert it's type by looking for a unique property like so:

```
enum Status {
    Pending = 1,
    Working = 2,
    Finish = 3
}

interface StatusMap {
 pending: Status.Pending;
 working: Status.Working;
 finish: Status.Finish;
}

const obj: StatusMap = { pending: Status.Pending, working: Status.Working, finish: Status.Finish };

function checkIfStatus(obj: StatusMap): 'Status' | 'NotStatusOrSomething' { 
 if ('pending' in obj) { 
   return 'Status'
  } else {
    return 'NotStatusOrSomething'
  }
}
```

Comment: I already use enum mapping. I use other enum to map it.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, enum is an Object in typescript.

So function could be

```
export function getName<T>(enumObject: T, value: any): string {
  Object.keys(enumObject).find(key => {
    return enumObject[key] === value;
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't need like that it will return result like 'Pending' or 'Working'
I want result is "Status"

Comment: @Viko - You want the type name, not the value?

Comment: @Igor yes I want type name.