# Why Angular duplicate enum values?

Tags: angular, enums, angular-material

Here's my enum:

```
export enum MyTypes {
  House = 1,
  Apartment = 2,
  Flat = 3,
  Studio = 4
}
```

if I cycle in a select this way:

```
<mat-select formControlName="myTypeField">
  <mat-option [value]="item.value" *ngFor="let item of myTypes"
    >{{ item.key }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

it shows:

```
1
2
3
4
House
Apartment
Flat
Studio
```

i.e. show both keys and values. Why?

Comment: how is defined `myTypes`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the way enums are compiled into objects by TypeScript. You can use TypeScript playground to see [how it's converted to JavaScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwLIE8AqWzADOcA3gFBxwASEyhwcAvHAIwA0FcAgmAIayok8ZgCYOlAGIAbXsLgBmcXADKMZABMAlhCZwALGQC+QA).

```
export enum MyTypes {
  House = 1,
  Apartment = 2,
  Flat = 3,
  Studio = 4
}

console.log(Object.keys(MyTypes));
// Prints: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "House", "Apartment", "Flat", "Studio"]
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fviymz

You'll need to first iterate the enum and get its own properties: [How to get names of enum entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111657/how-to-get-names-of-enum-entries)