# How to get enum key with enum value in typescript

Tags: typescript

In the project i am working on we have this widely used enum:

```
export enum A{
    Document = '1',
    Person = '2',
    Organization = '3',
    Equipment = '4',
    Location = '5',
    Event = '6',
    Link = '7',
    Target = '8',
}
```

Example: I want to get `Organization` with `A['3']`

Comment: You didn't mention this as a requirement, but I thought it might be useful to note that it's not possible for the compiler to infer the string literal value of the key during this kind of lookup, so its type will simply be `string | undefined` without an assertion (or just `string` if [`noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess) is disabled). Example: https://tsplay.dev/WJyQVm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get names of enum entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111657/how-to-get-names-of-enum-entries)

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73222621/how-to-get-enum-key-with-enum-value-in-typescript#comment129317972_73222621) @Behemoth That one is for numeric enums. String enums don’t have [reverse mappings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object keys

```
enum A {
    Document = '1',
    Person = '2',
    Organization = '3',
    Equipment = '4',
    Location = '5',
    Event = '6',
    Link = '7',
    Target = '8',
}

console.log(Object.keys(A)[Object.values(A).indexOf("1")]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to do that:

```
enum A{
    Document = '1',
    Person = '2',
    Organization = '3',
    Equipment = '4',
    Location = '5',
    Event = '6',
    Link = '7',
    Target = '8',
}

const param = '3';
const value = Object.entries(A).find(([_, v]) => v === param)![0];
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=67&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAgg3gKCsqARA9gY0qALlAXigHIBGYgGiRQAVgAnAZ3REJICZLrkB5egcwCGIAJYAvQbhEs2xAMxcUUAKIBHMCIAOEPLIAsilABksk6ayLEArIeTKAbrssA2W1CMiQAa1kB2NwAqggLA%20JYAHFwAvggImCyM%20JrBgtCWCgDccQn49oIANmDAbDwARgBWwJi4AHR49CLAjAAUMACUNQBmngAmzc0A2gD6FFD2ALpthAB8Y4QERMn0qW0AhAMADONZ2SDM%20cA1%20ej8zXmFwG1AA)