# Object.freeze() get both worlds

Tags: javascript, enums, key

```
const AnimeState = Object.freeze({
    Idle = 1,
    Walking=2,
    Running=3,
    Attacking = 4,
    Dead = 0,
    Uninitialized: -1
});

this.state = AnimeState.Uninitialized
```

Trying to get the **name** of the state, `console.log(AnimeState[this.state])` --- this doesn't work however, maybe because of me using the `Object.freeze()` method here. Is there a way to get both worlds?

**Desire:**
`console.log(AnimeState[this.state])` `if state === AnimeState.Uninitialized`, give me `Uninitialized` as `string`.

I followed this link: [How to get names of enum entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111657/how-to-get-names-of-enum-entries) and there, they pointed:

```
enum colors { red, green, blue };
```

Will be converted essentially to this:

```
var colors = { red: 0, green: 1, blue: 2,
               [0]: "red", [1]: "green", [2]: "blue" }
```

Because of this, the following will be true:

```
colors.red === 0
colors[colors.red] === "red"
colors["red"] === 0
```

This creates a easy way to get the name of an enumerated as follows:

```
var color: colors = colors.red;
console.log("The color selected is " + colors[color]);
```

Comment: `this.state` has the value you are looking for

Comment: @Konrad, yes `-1`, but I want it to give me the `Uninitialized` the name of the state.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a key in a JavaScript object by its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907419/how-to-get-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-by-its-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code is that you are try to use the assignment operator (=) instead of the colon (:) to define the property values of the `AnimeState` object. and also, you are using `camelCase` instead of `PascalCase` for the property names.

You can try this code :

```
const AnimeState = Object.freeze({
    IDLE: 1,
    WALKING: 2,
    RUNNING: 3,
    ATTACKING: 4,
    DEAD: 0,
    UNINITIALIZED: -1
});

let state = AnimeState.UNINITIALIZED;
console.log(Object.keys(AnimeState).find(key => AnimeState[key] === state));
```

If you that the object will be as `enum`:

```
enum AnimeState {
UNINITIALIZED = -1,
DEAD = 0,
IDLE = 1,
WALKING = 2,
RUNNING = 3,
ATTACKING = 4,
}
```

And then assign a value to state like this:

```
let state: AnimeState = AnimeState.UNINITIALIZED;
```

Comment: I followed this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111657/how-to-get-names-of-enum-entries --- which I didn't understand.

Comment: Read this : https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/a-complete-guide-to-creating-objects-in-javascript-b0e2450655e8/

Comment: That part I know, but, I was concerned with `enum` values.

Comment: @AlixBlaine I edited the answer for you

Comment: The name of the enum value currently set, so that, I can return a JSON saying: `{..., "state": "Walking"}` instead of a number that is harder to understand by the API consumer. Thank you.